# Android sdk will not install - crashes when checking for jdk

Tags: android

I have downloaded the java jdk, and the android sdk installer, but when I run the android sdk installer, it works fine until the screen where it checks for the java jdk.

It starts to not respond, then after about 15 seconds, a crash message pops up.

Any help with this issue?

Comment: Usually a crash message says something about why a crash occured. If, in your case, the crash message provide usefull information, share it.

Comment: Did you install the jdk first?  That's necessary...

Comment: I think he forgot updating the path. But I'm curious about the error message, I think it says exactly that.

Comment: It isn't really an error message, it just says, after a black box with java on the title bar: $(^Name) has stopped working Windows is checking for a solution to the problem. And it doesn't find a solution :(

Comment: The solution for me was to download the .zip package of the Android SDK. The installer seems corrupted.

Comment: Tony, from where'd you download the .zip?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

it may be a bit late, no solution on the internet worked for me and finally out of desperation I deleted the registery key:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\JavaSoft (not in Wow6432Node)`

And it worked! I hope I just saved someone from looking for a solution for two hours like I did.

Comment: Erm, just a bit late. I got it to work ages ago - my download manager was downloading a corrupt version :/ Accepted anyway :)

Comment: This also fixes an identical problem with "Android Studio" installer. Both current Android SDK and Android Studio suffer from this problem.

Comment: Worked! Just adding back the missing JDK_HOME environment (as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16574523/133516) doesn't work (or not enough)!

Answer (score 2):

The issue for me was that I did not have the 32-bit version of the JDK installed. I only had the 64-bit version.

Answer (score 1):

This answer might come a little late, but before installing the Android SDK I had about 6 versions of Java installed. Simply uninstalling every version and then installing the latest JDK for 32 or 64 bit will fix this crash.