# Android Studio installation on Windows 7 fails, no JDK found

Tags: android, installation, java, android-studio

I downloaded Android Studio and attempted to launch the program.

This is running on Windows 7 64-bit with Java 1.7. During the installation, my Java 1.7 is detected, and the rest of the installation goes through just fine. However, when attempting to launch the application from the desktop icon, nothing happens. Looking at the task manager, a new process from the CMD is loaded. This is because it's attempting to run the batch file `studio.bat`.

When I execute via CMD, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: cannot start Android Studio. No JDK found. Please validate
either ANDROID_STUDIO_JDK or JDK_HOME or JAVA_HOME points to valid
JDK installation. ECHO is off. Press any key to continue . . .
```

I've attempted to open the `idea` properties file to see if there was something I could configure for this `ANDROID_STUDIO_JDK` or something like that. However, I found nothing. I hope some of you can let me know if you were able to install this or if you are having problems as well.

Comment: I'm sharing that I have exactly the same issues. Looking for a solution. Updating the JDK x86 and x64 did not work

Comment: @RubenWeerts Thanks for the comment, i didnt know if i happen to be the one and only person. What have you tried?

Comment: You are not alone. It happned to me as well :( I have jdk 1.7 install with path JAVA_HOME still no luck.

Comment: We're aware of the issue and working on it. I've added a Known Issue and a workaround here yesterday in the meantime: http://tools.android.com/knownissues#as0.1

Comment: as a matter of fact, Windoze is not the greatest OS for software development…

Comment: For Android Studio 1, one [may use](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22956331/874502) `STUDIO_JDK` environment variable

Comment: How about 1.8 from 1.7?

Comment: For Windows 7 all Android Studio versions since 2022 don't work with symptoms like Java SDK, JAVA_HOME, etc  Don't waste the time - downgrade the version to Android Studio 4.0.

Answer (score 458, accepted):

Adding a system variable `JDK_HOME` with value `c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\` worked for me. The latest Java release can be downloaded [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html).

Additionally, make sure the variable `JAVA_HOME` is also set with the above location.

Comment: I can confirm that `Android Studio` works with JDK 1.7 as I have just verified it. And it's probably a good thing to set the system environment variable JDK_HOME (if not JAVA_HOME is set) to point to the installation of the Java JDK.

Comment: I too have jdk 1.7 but it doesn't launch. Wondering something to do with 64 bit.

Comment: Android Studio now launches successfully. Thank You

Comment: +1. @ssuperz28 that's how Google is :) like first three releases of Google Chrome that I tried (not literally 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, but I tried them some weeks apart) would crash on me straight away. It's easy to forget now that their browser didn't even have print option in its humble beginnings

Comment: I needed to set JAVA_HOME. JDK_HOME was set but JAVA_HOME was not. I set JAVA_HOME to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\ and it started up.

Comment: Well just in case you are not familiar on how to setup your JAVA_HOME you can read this link https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Setting+the+JAVA_HOME+Variable+in+Windows 

Big thanks for this solution! :)

Comment: +1 This MOSTLY worked for me. I am running 64 bit windows and JDK 1.7.0.  I tried adding both JDK_HOME and JAVA_HOME with "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\". It still would not load. However, I capitalized the "C" and removed the trailing slash and it works now: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0"

Comment: I had to go into system32 and rename java.exe to java.exe.old before it would see my JAVA_HOME path

Comment: For me it ignored the JAVA_HOME and JDK_HOME until I shut down the cmd and restarted it. Guessing it re-read the env vars and picked it up at that point. Had tried from cmd and just the old pointy-clicky in windows explorer.

Comment: Make sure you restart cmd after changing the environmental veriable. I was pulling my hair out for about 10 minutes trying to get it to work when finally I restarted cmd and it worked.

Comment: Win7, 64bit. I had to run the installer "As Administrator" and then it worked.

Comment: I have Win 7 (64 bit). I installed Android Studio and then set `JAVA_HOME` enviroment variable but it didn't work. So i had to unistall and install again Android Studio and then it worked.

Comment: Installing the latest JDK and setting JAVA_HOME did not work for me.  I had to install a Visual C++ package and that solved the issue. [blog to solution](http://www.satya-weblog.com/2013/06/android-studio-error-msvcr100-dll-is-missing.html)

Comment: Just an additional note, I had to reboot my PC before the environment variable(s) were picked up by the installer. I set JDK_HOME, JAVA_HOME and ANDROID_STUDIO_JDK all to the path to JDK. After that it installed and worked.

Comment: I had to also delete the JavaSoft registry key, as described here:http://stackoverflow.com/a/11603113/133516, in order to get the installer proceed.

Comment: @EdwinYip  Yes, deleting all Javasoft registry entries did the trick for me!

Comment: It's worth noting that some tools don't like the space in 'Program File' so on Windows it's best to set your `JAVA_HOME` variable using the abbreviated format: `C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.7.0_21` 

There's no need to have JDK_HOME and JAVA_HOME, just using JAVA_HOME is fine.

Comment: @2-Stroker: To your question, "Has anyone tried with 1.6, is 1.7 a requirement ?" I don't know about 1.6, but I just did it with 1.8.0

Comment: Also important: do not sourround the path in quotes "C:/Pro...". That might be obvious for some, but unfortunately not for me.

Comment: Do not add ; at the end

Answer (score 100):

OK, I figured out how fix this nasty bug.

### Before you start

Go to your Android Studio installation folder and locate the bin folder. Inside the bin folder, you will find **studio.bat**. Execute the file, and it'll show the error. If it is about the Java path then follow the tip 1.

### Tip 1

When you set the path `JAVA_HOME`, etc., make sure not to include `bin` at the end of the path. This solved the issue for me.

`JAVA_HOME` => `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21`

`path` => `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin`

It works fine with JDK 1.7 (I tried with 32 bit).

If you do so, you can see the initial screen as below.

[image]

### Tip 2

Are you getting the below error message?

> Your Android SDK is out of date or is missing templates. Please ensure
>   you are using SDK version 22 or later.

This error probably occurs, because you have reference to your older SDK (that you downloaded with [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29)) in your path variable. Go to Environment variables and remove any reference to the old SDK folder and point it to new SDK folder that is found inside the Android Studio installation folder.

Save and restart Studio, things should work as expected now.

### Tip 3

If you hate messing around with the path variable as given above by removing old references, simply follow the following steps to refer to new SDK path that comes with Studio.

`*Project Defaults* -> *Project Structure* -> Click "New" -> Select "Android SDK" -> Select the SDK` folder inside the studio installation.

Comment: Are you able to create project's, I have attempted to create a project and get the following error "Your Android SDK is out of date or is missing templates. Please ensure you are using SDK version 22 or later."

Comment: It seems that i am able to import existing projects and work on them. However unable to create new projects. I also configured the SDK location in the Android studio to my existing SDK instead of the one that came in the Android Studio bundle.

Comment: Yep same here. I don't know may be its an issue due to the existing Android SDK we downloaded.

Comment: Just update the Android SDK, you need revision 22 for SDK Tools and rev. 17 for Platform/Build-tools.

Comment: @chrkad Android Studio by default comes with 22. will check updating the sdk that came with eclipse.

Comment: @Carlo did you follow the steps mentioned above?

Comment: @MayuMayooresan yeah I did. What I had to do was to re-install everything. I think the problem with this came out of another problem I was having. The first problem was when installing the studio, it said that I didn't have the JDK (but I did), so a solution that I found was to uninstall x64 and install x86 - that fixed the first problem, but I think it caused the second one. So what I had to do was uninstall everything (studio, JDK and ADT), and re-install (this time x64 JDK) and of course remap the system variables. That did the trick and I was able to do a hello world app =) Thanks!

Comment: I ended up having to remove the double-quotes around my JAVA_HOME and JDK_HOME. In my environment properties, this:  
`JAVA_HOME`:  `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk 1.8.0_101"`  
became:  
`JAVA_HOME`:   `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk 1.8.0_101`  
(notice the lack of `"` in the latter)

Comment: FWIW I also added `%JDK_HOME%\bin%` to `Path` System variable list, and `%JDK_HOME%` to `Path` in my User variable list. I don't know if that's necessary, but once I got it working with everything I just went with it.

Answer (score 57):

With the last update of Android Studio, I have two versions of the IDE's launcher

One is called **studio.exe** and the other **studio64.exe** they are both on:

```
C:\Users\myUserName\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\bin
```

You have to launch the one that matches your Java version 64 or 32 bit

Comment: Juts one more clarification:
Android studio installer by default set shortcut to studio64.exe by default on Windows 7 64bit even my JDK is 32bit. When I changed shortcut to target "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio1\bin\studio.exe" everything works OK.

Comment: Yes, indeed, one needs to match studio.exe with 32bit JDK (JAVA_HOME) or studio64.exe with 64bit JDK (JAVA_HOME). Since I use 32 bit JDK for Eclipse I wish I could have two environments: 32 for eclipse and 64 for studio (I recall Python had a solution of virtual machine (or env) and one could toggle easily between 'profiles'.

Answer (score 18):

I had the same issue. I got resolved setting up correctly the environment variables in windows, for instance:

```
JAVA_HOME -> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45
path -> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin
```

Comment: This worked for me with 64 bit windows 7 and JDK version 1.7.0_21.

Comment: This solution is the RIGHT one. The point is APPENDING the bin folder path to the "path" in the Environment Variables

Answer (score 12):

I've `tried` so many of the answers here but `none of them works`, so I decided to `mix some of the answers` here and I am **successful**!

[image: Successtully running android]

**Step 1:** Go to the system properties by right-clicking on **My Computer** or by pressing windows button on typing **`This PC`** and right clicking on it and selecting **`Properties`**.

[image]

**Step 2:** Click the `advanced system settings` or **`Environment Variables`**

**Step 3:** Take note that there are 2 different variable. What you need to create is `system variables not user variables`, when you clicked new type the following

Variable name: `JAVA_HOME`

Variable value: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\` (Note: Please check if the path is right, sometimes it is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_25`)

**Step 4:** Run the android studio, no need to restart.

**Note:**

*`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\` depends entirely on the installation path of your `JDK` not `JRE` so don't be confused if you see something like the picture below. Just enter the location of your `jdk`, in my case it is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\`.

*`Do not include the bin folder` when you enter the Variable value.

[image]

[image]

**Edit:** **For Windows 8 and 10 Users:**  Try to run `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\studio.exe` instead of `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\binstudio64.exe`

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue. I am having 64-bit windows 8. I downloaded the android studio which worked on a 32-bit machine but not on my 64-bit.

The solution for me was pretty simple. I navigated to

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\bin`

there I saw 2 exe files **studio.exe** and **studio64.exe**. Normally my start menu was pointing to studio64.exe which always kept on giving me "The environmental variable JDK_HOME does not point to valid JVM". So then I clicked **studio.exe** and it worked :)

I hope this may help someone facing the same problem as me

Answer (score 9):

The path for the latest JDK. It worked very well.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If you are getting message "Your Android SDK is out of date…" — click "**Configure**" —> "**Project Defaults**" —> "**Project Structure**", pick "**SDKs**" —> "**Android SDK**" and in a "**Build Target**" choose "**Android 4.2.2**". Click "OK". Now it should work fine.

Comment: Im no longer getting the Android SDK is out of date, I have the most recent SDK that i previous had configured with Eclipse. However with using the Android Studio i want to configure it to see that SDK. Im having a issue where it doesnt recongize it for all the SDK related buttons in the program. See my other thread here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16576960/android-studio-issue-with-android-sdk-on-windows-7

Comment: @Alberto, maybe you didn't set path variables?

Comment: i've set only JAVA_HOME variable

Answer (score 6):

I got the problem that the installation stopped by the "**$(^name) has stopped working**" error. I have installed the Java SE Development kit already, and also set both SDK_HOME and JAVA_HOME that point to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21"

My laptop installed with Windows 7 64 bits

So I tried to install the 32-bit version of the Java SE Development kit, and set my JAVA_HOME to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_21", restart and the installation worked OK.

Answer (score 5):

This problem has been fixed in Android Studio v0.1.1, so just update Android Studio and it should work.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes you can resolve this type of issue by setting environment variables **so the process looks for the JDK in the right spot**.

Another approach is to **figure out where the process is looking, then put your JDK there.**

I've had lots of success using [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) from Sysinternals:

1. Start -> Run -> `procmon`
2. Go to the `Filter` menu, then select `Filter...`
3. Set `Event Class` `is` `File System` then `Include`
4. `Add`, then `OK`

This will filter down to all the file system operations taking place on your machine.

You could try filtering based on the result of the File System operation:

- Right click on the `Result` column, then `Exclude 'SUCCESS'`

You can also quite easily filter based on the process name, either from the `Filter...` menu option or by right clicking on the `Process Name` column and selecting `Include 'process.exe'`.

Once you find the file system operation that's failing, the `Path` column will tell you where to put your JDK.

I've found this to be very empowering. Especially compared to the frustrating process of changing environment variables by trial and error.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and I am seeing a lot of entries in process monitor for Android Studio process. For many entries it is showing "NAME NOT FOUND" in "Result" column. What to do now?

Answer (score 3):

My issue was caused because I have an `&` character in my Windows user name, so when installed in the default path I was getting the following error after running `bin/studio.bat`

```
                                               |
                                               v notice broken path
The system cannot find the file C:\Users\Daniel \studio64.exe.vmoptions.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/intellij/idea/Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.intellij.idea.Main
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: com.intellij.idea.Main.  Program will exit.
```

So I uninstalled and reinstalled it to program files and it launches fine now.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't get this to work no matter which environment variables I set. So I simply put a copy of the JDK into my Android Studio installation folder.

1. Copy the contents of the JDK installation (for example, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_21`)
2. Paste them into the installation directory of the Android Studio (for example, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio`)

I somewhat assumed that the issue was caused by having the x64 version of the JDK installed. But what was especially confusing was the fact that I could start Android Studio just fine when I started the `studio.bat` as an Administrator (even though the environment variables were set for my personal user account).

`studio.bat` will look for several valid options when determining which JDK to use.

> `:: Locate a JDK installation directory which will be used to run the IDE.`
>   `:: Try (in order): ANDROID_STUDIO_JDK, ..\jre, JDK_HOME, JAVA_HOME.`

As explained above, I picked the `..\jre` option.

Answer (score 3):

Today I found another situation when this problem occures - when you have several JDK, defined in JAVA_PATH. I have:

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\JAVA\JDK\jdk1.6.0_38;C:\JAVA\JDK\jdk1.7.0_10
```

So I received this problem with Android Studio setup

But when I've removed one of JDK - problem has been solved:

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\JAVA\JDK\jdk1.7.0_10
```

Installation wisard found my jdk and i had a nice night to study studio.

But unfortunatelly even installed studio doesn't work with several jdk.
Does anybody know how to fix it?

I hope I've helped someone

Answer (score 3):

**MAKE SURE YOU RESTART ANDROID STUDIO**

Even though I should know better and swear I did, make sure you restart studio after making these changes as it clearly does not check them on every build (which to me makes sense that system/user variables should only be read once on startup)

Anyway, yea... Make sure you restart after you make these changes.

**Path** = to the bin folder in the jdk folder (path already exists)

**JAVA_HOME** = to the jdk folder

Answer (score 3):

**Windows 64 bit, JDK 64 bit (Solution that worked for me)**
Tried all the above solutions, and None of them worked, I have been trying to solve it for the past few days and now I did it successfully. For me the problem was when I first installed Android Studio my JDK version was 1.7, then after installing I updated the JDK to 1.8, then I removed the old JDK folder and everything was messed up, even uninstalling and reinstalling android studio randomly didn't solve the issue.

**Below is the solution that worked for me**

1. Uninstall Android Studio.
2. clean temp files and android studio C:\Users\Username.AndroidStudio1.5
3. Uninstall JDK.
4. Now without JDK try to install Android Studio and now it will show the message that it can't find any JDK. Stop installation
5. Install JDK 1.7 or 1.8 (Set JAVA_HOME, JDK_HOME, path Environment variables as explained by everybody above)
6. Install Android Studio.
7. Done. Enjoy and happy coding.

Answer (score 3):

1. Add JAVA_HOME and JDK_HOME system environment variables.
2. Right-click
   android studio (the 64 version if that's your OS and JDK) and go to
   compatibility tab and set "Run as administrator" to true.
3. Run android studio and high-five me virtually when it works.
4. If that fails, try "where java" in cmd.exe. If it lists c:\system32\java.exe first, then rename the file and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Install the latest [JDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit) in your system from *[JDK 7 and JRE 7 Installation Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/)*.

```
JAVA_HOME -> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_4
path -> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_4\bin
```

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, I was unable (even after adding JDK_HOME) to launch Studio via either the shortcut or studio.exe itself.  I had to first run bin/studio.bat (mentioned in the original question).
After the first successful launch, I'm able to start it with the shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

If setting the `JAVA_HOME` variable doesn't work for you, set:

```
STUDIO_JDK=C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_172
```

Where the path points to your JDK installation
This is the only thing which works for me in Windows 32bit with Android 10 and up.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a 64 bit windows OS, pointing the JAVA_HOME system variable to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_21
```

Will work when

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21
```

fails to work.

Comment: I had the same issue. It's because you're running studio64.exe instead of studio.exe. If you have JDK x86 installed then you need to run 32bit version of studio.

Answer (score 0):

You need 1.7 JDK installed on your system. Add a system variable with:

- name: ANDROID_STUDIO_JDK
- path: your [JDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit) path (for example, `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21`)

  - See more at *[FIX: Android Studio - Installation Issues on Windows 7 | ERROR: cannot start Android Studio. No JDK found.](http://www.codecows.com/2013/05/fix-android-studio-installation-issues.html#.dpuf)*

Answer (score 0):

TRY TO INSTALL 32BIT JDK

if you have jdk installed and had set up the System Varibles such as JAVA_HOME or JDK_HOME
and tried click back and then next ,you might have installed the 64bit JDK,just download the 32bit jdk and install it.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the latest jdk version

JAVA_HOME to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin
Set the PATH to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin

I restarted the STUDIO and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10, restarting the installer and running as admin worked for me.

Comment: I also found that I had to open `studio64.exe` and not `studio.exe` to get it to run.

Answer (score 0):

To complete this stack of possible solutions: For me the problem was, that I did not execute the Android-Studio-Setup as administrator. Running it as administrator then made me able to install Android-Studio.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was that I had changed the GC vm arg to `-XX:+UseParallelGC` in the `C:\Users\<username>\.AndroidStudio2.1\studio64.exe.vmoptions` file.  That's what I use in Eclipse and I was trying various things to get AndroidStudio half way as efficent as Eclipse.  I restored the GC to `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the original question is that, might be you are opening android studio from 32 bit shortcut icon of android studio, try to open from icon "studio64" located under .../bin/ where android studio setup is install.

Answer (score 0):

In case you had it running but Now it doesn't Launch.
I deleted the `C:\Users\<NAME>\.AndroidStudio<version>\` folder and it worked.