# Android Studio does not launch after installation

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I've just downloaded the new Android Studio IDE released today, and installed it.  When I double-click the icon to launch it, nothing happens.  I've tried every shortcut to it, as well as the .exe in the installation folder.

I've also tried restarting the machine, uninstalling / restarting, and installing to a folder location without spaces.  Does someone know why Android Studio won't start?

Comment: Does Google support this product?  Also, I'm hearing anecdotal reports that it won't run on Windows 8.  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15/android

Comment: A lot of people are having issues http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574189/android-studio-installation-issues-on-windows-7?noredirect=1#comment23816203_16574189

Comment: Did you try admin run?

Comment: yeah I tried admin run. I'll try the solutions in the other issue, and then close this as a duplicate if necessary.

Comment: Yup, adding the JDK_HOME setting to my Java 1.7 directory fixed it.  I'll vote to close as a duplicate.

Comment: Please see the following Thread i have started, Alot of people have resolved their issues including myself. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574189/android-studio-installation-issues-on-windows-7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574189/android-studio-installation-issues-on-windows-7)

Comment: By the way @RobertHarvey, Android Studio is the new official IDE for android development.  It was announced at Google I/O this morning.

Comment: Yes, I have the link.  Awesome.

Comment: Hey, it is not a duplicate, the other question is about install problems, this one is about issues AFTER the install

Comment: Do we have to brace for a flood of question from folks who want to run an unsupported alpha product now?

Comment: We're aware of the issue and working on it. I've added a Known Issue and a workaround here yesterday in the meantime: http://tools.android.com/knownissues#as0.1

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I set my `JDK_HOME` environment variable to point to my Java (1.7) JDK path, and it worked.

My JDK path was:

> c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21

but it will vary depending on the version of your JDK.

For directions in setting PATH variables for windows see: http://java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

Comment: My google skills are failing me...how do I edit the "JDK_HOME" variable? As in where is it located? I have Java(1.7) installed

Comment: Go to the Environment Variables (Control Panel -> System -> Advanced System Settings -> Advanced (tab) -> Environment Variables). Then add JDK_HOME with the correct path under System Variables.

Comment: Also, note it isn't enough to add java home to the PATH variable, it is mandatory to create JDK_HOME

Comment: Looks like smart screen on windows 8 is the problem

Comment: For those who are on Linux Systems, make sure your desktop file contains this line:
`Exec=JDK_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/icedtea-7/" /path/to/your/.../android-studio/bin/studio.sh`
Replace the JDK_HOME path to whatever yours is.

Comment: Worked like a charm :)