# Android Studio doesn't launch: Could not find or load main class com.intellij.idea.Main

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

Being new in Android devopmnet, I have been using Android Studio for development, but suddenly it doesn't work anymore.

The program doesn't launch anymore, and If I execute the *studio.bat* from Command Prompt, I get the following error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class com.intellij.idea.Main

I have seen other posts about Android Studio not launching (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574189/android-studio-installation-on-windows-7-fails-no-jdk-found) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574544/android-studio-does-not-launch-after-installation)), but neither of them solve my problem. I have set `PATH` variables for both `JAVA_HOME` and `JDK_HOME` correctly to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07`

As I have mentioned, Android Studio used to work and I don't have any idea why it has stopped working. Any clue?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm getting the same on Linux.

Comment: I started getting this when my system after a studio update suddenly crashed due to power shortage

Comment: For those who have been getting this error on Linux, for me the problem turned out to be that I had accidentally un-checked "preserve directory structure" when extracting the android studio .zip file.

Comment: If you are trying to launch from the command line follow https://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/438193

Answer (score 2):

For android studio 1.3.1
go to environment variable and create new variable and give it a name JAVA_HOME and in path use this **C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.7.0_71**.
I hope that can help you.

Answer (score 2):

if you  have just  used copy paste  of exe file it will show  this message so go  in Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin and click on exe file.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after updating the Android studio. I was not able to launch it from click on Android Studio icon and after running `./studio.sh` it was giving me same error

I follow the below step and solved the problem.

1. I downloaded the studio and install it in the new directory.
2. After installation success, copy all the files & folders and paste and replace it into old location where studio was installed.

Answer (score 0):

Having JAVA_HOME set to point latest JDK version (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79) will make the Android studio work. Make sure the path is correct. Seems that JDK_HOME is not needed.
can refer [Installing Android Studio (Not working)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27109216/installing-android-studio-not-working/30490028#30490028)

Answer (score 0):

If you have recently uninstalled and reinstalled Android Studio and had previously pinned the Android Studio icon to your Task Bar or Start Menu, it may be that this icon no longer looks for the new installation. 
Delete it and re-pin it and all will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue while launching the `studio.exe` file. The actual problem was I have downloaded the 64-bit version of Android studio. But my computer supports only 32 bit.

So I downloaded 32-bit version and installed.

Now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Well after searching allover the web, failed to get solution till i decided to reinstall android studio. same folder changed nothing didn't delete anything just reinstalled and boom works as before

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you update Studio and new version is installed and previous one is in process of deletion:  at the main time if PC shut down or suddenly crashed due to power cut etc. Then this problem will appear:

> could not find main class com/intellij/idea/main

**Solution:**

1. Go to this path "C:\Program Files\Android", there you will find two Android Studio Folders.
   [image]
2. Find which one is latest: (Latest name wold be "**Android Studio1**") && (Old version would be **Android Studio**)
3. Delete old one(if you don't need it any more) and launch latest exe on this path:

> C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\bin
> [image]

Answer (score 0):

Open the Installer and download it again and you can select delete previous versions to clear confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Open **studio64** instead of *studio*

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I found Answer: you just make wrong `shortcut`(just <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>) for launchfile(exe). You must make shortcut following this method:

> Right mouse click and select make shortcut menu.

Answer (score -1):

**Please follow the below steps,**

1. Go to My Computer -> Properties -> Advance System Settings
2. System properties window will appear
3. Go to Advance tab -> Environment Variables -> New
4. Add or update JAVA_HOME path as expected.
5. Optionally you can also add or update JDK_HOME if you have JDK installed in your PC

[image]

Comment: Your JAVA_HOME is invalid: C:\Program Files\Java\jre || JAVA_HOME is for reference to jdk. 
But it's very clear why you did not have any problems because in systeam variable, you set Java_Home correctly.

Comment: @MehrshadFarzaneh What would be JDK_HOME then?