# Installing Android Studio (Not working)

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to instal Android Studio for Windows but I get an error: "Could not find main class com/intellij/idea/Main"

I installed the 64 bit jdk and created an environment variable called JAVA_HOME and linked this to my jdk as so: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71"

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: the error is: 12Could not find main class com/intellij/idea/Main" @Shriram

Comment: So, did you work this out?

Comment: @Kim If you're having the same problem, just reinstall android studio. That's what worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have installed 64bit ?

Generally for 64bit installation default path will be "c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_71"

Another thing to check if your java installation ( 64bit is compatible ) is fine.

a. open command prompt.

b. cd {your java installation}\jdk1.7.0_71\bin

c. type "java" and "java -version" ( See if both command works )

Comment: I have both 32 and 64 bit JDK installed. Originally I had the 32 bit JDK but when installing Android Studio it said I needed to have 64, so I went ahead and installed 64bit JDK. Also, both commands DO work.

Comment: Then you have to make sure JAVA_HOME is pointing to 64 bit Java SDK. post that restart your Android studio and try.

Comment: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71" thats where my JAVA_HOME is pointing to. I've already tried all of this. I even restarted my computer. Doesnt work!

Comment: Please try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574189/android-studio-installation-on-windows-7-fails-no-jdk-found a similar issue is encountered and fixed.

Comment: Doesn't seem very helpful. I've made the JAVA_HOME and JDK_HOME variables with the correct values and I still dont get anything :(

Answer (score 1):

Having JAVA_HOME set to point latest JDK version (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79) will make the Android studio work. Make sure the path is correct. Seems that JDK_HOME is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Add a system variable JDK_HOME with value c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\

Comment: if you read the question you'll realise I've already done that

Comment: Your question mentions you've added ``JAVA_HOME`` @Abdul-MaliKR is saying to add ``JDK_HOME`` and point to the same path that is what I have on my setup and never had a problem

Comment: misread that! So should I also remove JAVA_HOME or keep both? @Boardy

Comment: @Boardy Still doesnt work. I even restarted my computer

Comment: Hmm, strange, have you also got a JRE installed as this also needs to be installed and match the JDK, i.e. both x86 or x64

Answer (score 0):

Just install java jdk and jre and runtime environment and java 8 update 45 in 64 bit if your computer is 64 bit and 32 bit if your computer is 32bit and then in your environment variable just remove the /bin from it.