# Error launching studio: "Could not find main class com/intellij/idea/Main" when installing Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I'm currently having an issue installing Android studio. Whenever I clicked on `studio.exe` to begin installing it pops up with an error message saying: `Could not find main class com/intellij/idea/Main`

[image]

I've searched through but still no way out. I have installed Java and configure my environment variables.

Please, what could have gone wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27109216/installing-android-studio-not-working/30490028

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Windows**

To install `Android Studio` on Windows, proceed as follows:

- If you downloaded an **.exe** file (recommended), double-click to launch it.
- If you downloaded a **.zip** file, unpack the ZIP, copy the `android-studio` folder into your `Program Files` folder, and then open the `android-studio > bin` folder and launch **studio64.exe** (for 64-bit machines) or **studio.exe** (for 32-bit machines).

Follow the setup wizard in Android Studio and install any SDK packages that it recommends.

Comment: I've done that but still getting the same error. Please read my question again. Thanks.

Comment: It's working now using your system. I extracted the files before installation. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For me in Windows helped java version correct path in file
`c:\Users\ *{you}* \.IntelliJIdea*{idea version}*\config\idea64.exe.jdk`. Its happens when i used plugin switching env to java 1.6, possible too old for 2019.3.

Answer (score 0):

Go to environment variable and create new variable and give it a name `JAVA_HOME` and in path use this `C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.7.0_71` (arrange JDK accordingly)