# My android studio does not open. It seems to start for a second

Tags: android-studio

I have android studio in windows 7. Perhaps android is 32 bit  and java is 64 bit. How to check it? Will it create problems? My android studio does not open. It seems to start for a second. Then closes. I could not find studio.bat in bin folder. I clicked studio.exe. It says "could not find main class com/intellij/idea/Main". What should I do?

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000764404-Pycharm-error-Could-not-find-main-class-com-intellij-idea-main

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio doesn't launch: Could not find or load main class com.intellij.idea.Main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155180/android-studio-doesnt-launch-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-com-intellij-id)