# error in launching intellij idea cannot find com/intellij/idea/main

Tags: intellij-idea

[Android Studio doesn't launch: Could not find or load main class com.intellij.idea.Main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155180/android-studio-doesnt-launch-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-com-intellij-id)

I am facing the same issue as Intellij as mentioned above but I am not using android

Comment: Reinstall the IDE from http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html.

Comment: tried it is  it not working

Comment: What OS do you use?

Comment: windows 10 migrated from windows7

Comment: Try installing via https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox/app/, delete IDE folders (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519). Disable the antivirus.

Comment: i deleted ide folder but when install it again the IDE folder are not formed

Comment: Toolbox installs into the different location than the standard Windows installer, see if it helps. Antivirus may be blocking the installation or removing the IDE files, so make sure it's disabled.

Comment: it is my office laptop and it was working fine earlier i cannot disable antivirus

Comment: Contact your IT helpdesk so that they whitelist IDE installation.