# I can't install/launch Android Studio for Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: android, ide, intellij-idea, android-studio

I downloaded the IDE from here [Android Developer Site](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) and after the instalation wizard, the IDE doesnt launch even of the start menu

Thanks!

Answer (score 32):

First make sure jdk is installed to begin with. In my case it wasnt and I presumed that it was. Then doing the environment variable worked for me.

Try setting up a system variable

name: ANDROID_STUDIO_JDK

path: your jdk path e.g. 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdkXXXXX' (where *XXXX* is your the version installed in your computer)

[Source](http://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/1ee2ea/google_announces_android_studio_a_new_development/c9zfklt)

[Creating a Custom System Environment Variable](http://www.howtogeek.com/51807/how-to-create-and-use-global-system-environment-variables/)

Comment: Still not working for me.. I have the 64bit JDK.
Any other suggestions?

Comment: did u make sure to use your actual path?

Answer (score 7):

Setting the ANDROID_STUDIO_JDK as system variable in Windows 7 - 64 bit operating system solved the issue.

### Unlike what is in the post, I received a different version of the error, below:

### Error launching Android Studio

No JVM installation found. Please install a 64-bit JDK.
If you already have a JDK installed, define a JAVA_HOME variable in Computer > System Properties > System Settings > Environment Variables.

Setting ANDROID_STUDIO_JDK solves the above error as well.

Comment: you're the man. for 64 bit windows, you need to set this exact env var to the JDK Install folder, not JAVA_HOME or JDK_HOME. And don't try to help the computer by putting in those double quotes either..

Answer (score 3):

go to control panel -> System -> Advance system settings -> Environment variable

then under system variable click new enter variable name JDK_HOME and variable value C:\programfiles\java\jdk, this path can be different on different computer. Then start android studio

Comment: I think you meant JAVA_HOME not "JDK"_HOME

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use this automated fix: http://enccompany.com/androidstudio/AndroidStudioFixer.exe

[Android Studio installation on Windows 7 fails, no JDK found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574189/android-studio-installation-issues-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but from :
[this site](http://javatechig.com/2013/05/19/installing-android-studio/) 
i solved that.

the problem was the Environments Variables...

Answer (score 0):

I had to install the x86 versions, verses the x64 versions of the JDK.  I am using Windows 8.  However this was preventing me from installing the Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

In your case
No JDK found. Please validate either ANDROID_STUDIO_JDK, JDK_HOME or JAVA_HOME points to valid JDK installation.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the "C:\Program Files\Android\android-studio\bin\studio.bat".  it told me that my JAVA_HOME path was not set.  (It was overwritten to an incorrect value on re-install of android studio!!)  Also ensure that your PATH variable has the "%JAVA_HOME\bin" in it.

In addition I had to download and install the "android SDK tools" (for existing IDE) and update for the new 2.2
After install of SDK tools; start android studio->configure->project defaults->project structure [and point the SDK path to new install; also check the Java SDK path]

Note: that my Java_home path got "Overwritten" on re-install of android studio...and I had to go in and correct it back to my 1.7 directory!  so make sure that your PATH includes the bin directory for the correct JAVA as well as your JAVA_HOME pointing to the correct JDK (1.7) in this case.