# Android Studio on Windows 8 64-bit can't find JVD

Tags: java, android, windows-8, android-studio

I just bought new laptop and I have problems with running android studio. I have read over 20+ questions/answers about this but exact problem but with me it's not working. The problem: After installing the studio (successfully), when I try to run it it sais: `No JVM installation found. Please install 64-bit JDK.` Note that I have already installed JDK, specified `JAVA_HOME, and JDK_HOME` as a variable (100%) that the path is correct (`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25"`). I have also java installed. I have tried reinstalling the studio, reinstalling java and almost everything that I could find on google, but nothing works. Eqlipse, works just fine though. It is not my first time trying to install Android Studio, but I can't figure this one out. I have read from here: [Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574189/android-studio-installation-on-windows-7-fails-no-jdk-found) and here [Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16575536/i-cant-install-launch-android-studio-for-windows-7-64-bit) mostly, and from a lot more like threads like this, but I cant solve my problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Please show the value of JAVA_HOME and JDK_HOME

Comment: Both are set to C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25

Comment: If you have it installed in _C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25_ then it's a 32-bit JDK.

Comment: @divoom12 It clearly wants the 64bit JDK, you have the 32bit installed.

Comment: Okay. I'm downloading x64 version now, and I will try. All this time, I thought that x64 stands for 32-bit, and x84, for 64-bit. I don't know why. I will try and write back. Thanks.

Comment: By default, 64-bit Windows programs get installed in _C:\Program Files_ and 32-bit programs in _C:\Program Files (x86)_.

Comment: Okay. Now it works. Thanks a lot!! Why x64 stands for 64-bit, and x86 for 32. Why not 32 --> x32? What is the logic behind this?

Comment: Because x86 already existed (from the 8086 processor).  x64 was chosen for 64 bit as being completely logical ;)

Answer (score 1):

What you have installed seems to be 32 bit version as it is getting Installed in "Program Files (x86)",Download and install 64bit JDK and that should automatically get installed in "Program Files" folder and not in "Program Files (x86)".

Download 64bit installer of JDK

This might solve the problem.