# Android Studio - Issue with Android SDK on Windows 7

Tags: android, intellij-idea, windows-7-x64, android-sdk-tools, android-studio

Im having a issue with the latest developer tool announced at Google i/o 2013 "Android Studio". I have successfully installed the program and am able to launch just fine. I can import exsisting projects and edit them just fine. However when i attempt to click the SDK Manager icon or the AVD Manager icon, Or when i attempt to create a new project. I get the following error "Please specify Android SDK" Now, I have already gone into **File > Other Settings > Default Project Structure > under "Platform Settings" SDK's** .
I have created a Android SDK item with the source to my Android SDK folder.

Therefore i don't understand why Android Studio doesnt recognize it. The only thing that im doing somewhat different is not using the included sdk folder in the actual Android Studio folder. However when trying it, it says its not a real SDK home.

Any idea's, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try updating your Android SDK to r22 http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r22-windows.exe

I had the same issue, once I updated to the latest SDK, Android Studio was able to find the android-sdk folder.

Comment: This resolved the issue, Just uninstall the previous SDK r21 and reinstalled my entire SDK with the r22 installer and it worked.

Comment: Using the Android SDK Manager (Linux) I had to install the relevant 'SDK build tools' which fixed the issue for me too.

Answer (score 7):

I was having this same issue. First download the latest SDK as described by dues71 and put it someplace you will remember (for instance C:\AndroidSDK). In Android Studio select your project and select File->Project Structure (or select the [image: icon] icon ). On the left, under Project Settings select Modules and select the Dependencies tab. In row that says "Module SDK" select "New..." and select "Android SDK". Navigate to root sdk directory (i.e. C:\AndroidSDK) and select OK. Select the latest Android SDK. It will now index the directory which may take some time, but after that is complete it should work.

Comment: That doesn't tell you how to add Android SDK.  That only tells you how to add JAVA_HOME and Oracle Java JDK.

Answer (score 0):

I tryed to update Android SDK to latest 22 version and then restarted IDE (I had same issue on Intellij IDEA 13 EAP), I think this would work on Android Studio too.

Answer (score 0):

Just press ctrl+f9 than the error will remove automatically.Sometimes it may happen that the SDK is already there but not linked with the project.You should click on make project or ctrl+f9 than everything will be fine.