# Android Studio does not start

Tags: windows-7, android-studio

After installing Android Studio, I started it. But it doesn't start. I open the Task Manager to see more than two execution sequence

**`Cmd.exe`** and **`conhost.exe`**

My system version is Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Studio install on Windows 7 fails, no JDK found?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574189/android-studio-install-on-windows-7-fails-no-jdk-found)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a bug of Android Studio 0.1v

http://tools.android.com/knownissues#as0.1

> - **Open Start menu > computer > System Properties >  Advanced System
>     Properties**
> - In the **Advanced tab > Environment Variables**, add new    system
>     variable **`JAVA_HOME`** that points to your JDK folder, for example **`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21`**

Answer (score 1):

have you seen this thread? has details on windows 7 64bit issues and how to solve.

[Android Studio installation on Windows 7 fails, no JDK found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574189/android-studio-installation-issues-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar problem on Windows 7 x64 professional edition. Please note following steps to fix this problem.

1. tools.jar is missing from required path if you are using jdk1.7 x64 bit version.
2. Please install x86 version of jdk1.7
3. Set JDK_HOME="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_67" and update path environment variable as path="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin"
4. Launch 32 bit application from /android-studio\bin folder.

I tested and verified these steps on windows 7 with 32 bit jdk1.7

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Start menu > computer > System Properties > Advanced System
   Properties
2. In the Advanced tab > Environment Variables, add new
   system variable STUDIO_SDK that points to your JDK folder, for
   example C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21

Comment: this is a direct copy-and-paste of the (2 year old!) accepted answer!

Answer (score -1):

Here is a tutorial on Youtube that shows you how to install it.  It seems you must have an environmental variable called JDK_HOME and set it to your JDK directory. The link to the video is http://youtu.be/TTrUX1kUpDo

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -1):

Here　is　some tutorials on eoeAdroid.com that show you how to install it and setup it, and some others tips.

http://www.eoeandroid.com/thread-275496-1-1.html

install on windows7: http://www.eoeandroid.com/thread-275387-1-1.html

install on mac: http://www.eoeandroid.com/thread-275478-1-1.html

and this is a video tutorial:  http://www.eoeandroid.com/thread-275470-1-1.html

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.