# Error to run Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have installed Android Studio and I followed all steps described [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html#download)

But when I start `studio.sh` I got an error with this message:

> 'tools.jar' is not in Android Studio classpath. Please ensure JAVA_HOME points to JDK rather than JRE

Can anyone here help me with this?

Comment: this link may help you [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16578321/android-studio-cant-start)

Comment: I don't understand the down voting. He asked a simple question. Is it a requirement to be a douche and down vote it?  The community should support new users, not try to run them off.

Comment: I also had the same problem and found this post from Stackoverflow. Solved the issue. [Stack Overflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27528652/tools-jar-seems-to-be-not-in-android-studio-classpath-on-windows-8)

Answer (score 95):

Check if your Java JDK is installed correctly

```
dpkg --list | grep -i jdk
```

If not, install JDK

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

After the installation you have to enable the jdk

```
update-alternatives --display java
```

Check if Ubuntu uses Java JDK 8

```
java -version
```

If all went right the answer should be something like this:

```
java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
```

Check what compiler is used

```
javac -version
```

It should show something like this

```
javac 1.8.0_91
```

Finally, add JAVA_HOME to the environment variable

Edit `/etc/environment` and add `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle` to the end of the file

```
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

Append to the end of the file

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

You will then have to reboot, you can do this from the terminal with:

```
sudo reboot
```

In case you want to remove the JDK

```
sudo apt-get remove oracle-java8-installer
```

Comment: 'dpkg --list | grep -i jdk' showed that I had old Sun's Java version 6, glad to get rid of that one.

Comment: I didn't have to edit /etc/environment for this to work.

Comment: thanks its really helpful no need to edit JAVA HOME path

Comment: i am not well in it but i got such messege : "OpenJDK shows intermittent performance and UI issues. We recommend using the Oracle JRE/JDK" What does it mean?

Comment: they recommend you use Oracle's version of Java, the OpenJdk Java has issues

Answer (score 42):

```
 sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

That's all in **ubuntu 11**

Comment: I already solved it. I can't use apt-get because I'm using Fedora. I use Yum. But thanks anyway.!

Comment: Thanks @Elshan, worked like a charm. The interesting thing, is that after I did that Android Studio runs, but there's no JAVA_HOME variable set up. But I don't care since it works.

Comment: I cannot revoke my upvote, but I realized that it caused the version 6 JDK to install, and Android Studio is throwing errors like hell. So it doesn't work like a charm.

Comment: @CsabaToth, I believe this might be because you're using an older Ubuntu distribution, on my 13.10 it definitely installs openjdk version 7.

Comment: @EugenevanderMerwe I did a dist upgrade, I'll check on that.

Comment: It also works for me in linux mint cinnamon 17.. but Android Studio prefers OracleJDK to be installed.. anyways i dont care if my stuff is working :D

Answer (score 17):

This is caused by having JAVA JRE installed as opposed to JAVA JDK.

The solution is simple:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

http://www.maxmakedesign.co.uk/development/2013/android-studio-tools-jar-classpath/

Comment: It helped me  "sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk"

Comment: This helped. On Ubuntu 15.10 I had to start studio with `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/ ./studio.sh`

Comment: "sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk" This is the secret.. Nice! Thanks! +1

Answer (score 16):

The error is self explanatory, you need to set your environment variable to JDK path instead of JRE here is it

```
JDK_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07
```

check the path for linux

and here is possible duplicate [Android Studio not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16578321/android-studio-cant-start?lq=1)

Comment: Sorry. I didn´t told about my operation system: linux(Fedora 18 64). I have created and configured JAVA_HOME and PATH but I´m still getting this message.

Answer (score 9):

Widows 7 64 bit.

1. JAVA_HOME point to my JRE (NOT JDK) directory
2. Coping of tools.jar from JDK\lib directory to ANDROIDSTUDIO\lib directory solve the problem

Comment: Works prefectly on windows 7 64 bits!

Comment: This worked perfectly when I installed Android Studio via Wine on Mac OSX El Capitan.

Answer (score 8):

in OpenSuSE 13.1 and some 13.2 versions you also need to:

- install `java-1_7_0-openjdk-devel` package
- change the JAVA_HOME path when starting the studio:

For x86:
`JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0/ sh studio.sh`

For x64:
`JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib64/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0/ sh studio.sh`

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem on a new installed Linux Mint 16. To fix this you just need to type command

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

And that's it. You even do not need to add repositiries or creating JAVA_HOME in your environment.

Answer (score 4):

First check if the Java JDK is installed correctly:

```
dpkg --list | grep -i jdk
```

If not, install the JDK:

1. Download the latest version of the JDK from Oracle: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html
2. Extract it to the appropriate location in your machine. Get the extract location:

   `vi ~/.bashrc` or `vi ~./ bash_profile`

   ```
   JAVA_HOME=/home/user/installs/jdk1.7.0_40
   PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin
   ```

   `source ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.bash_profile`
3. After the installation you can check it:

   ```
   java -version
   which java
   ```

   If all things are correct then the right the answer should be something like this:

   > java version "1.7.0_40"
   >   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
   >   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode)
4. Append the following statement to studio.sh the file in android-studio/bin directory:

   ```
   JAVA_HOME=/home/user/installs/jdk1.7.0_40
   ```

Finally start your Android Studio with the following command:

```
./studio.sh
```

Answer (score 4):

On ubuntu I have tried all the methods that are described here but none worked.

What I did in the end was to:

- download JDK from oracle, extract the archive
- edit `android-studio/bin/studio.sh` and add at the top

  export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/jdk
- save the file and `cd android-studio/bin` and launch Android Studio: `./studio.sh`

Answer (score 4):

For me, running **Fedora 22**  with Gnome 16.2, this [solution](http://metzonalli.net/index.php/2015/06/22/jdk-required-tools-jar-seems-to-be-not-in-studio-classpath-error-while-installing-android-studio-on-centos-7/) helped me.
In short, you should install the java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel, the *development* files of the JDK.

Open the Terminal and search for the latest version of the JDK development package:

```
$ dnf search jdk-devel
Last metadata expiration check performed 12:44:51 ago on Mon Aug  3 22:20:24 2015.
============================ N/S Matched: jdk-devel ============================
java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64 : OpenJDK Development Environment
java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-debug.x86_64 : OpenJDK Development Environment with
                                      : full debug on
$ sudo dnf install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is a bug on Fedora 20. The bug is very odd: if I have Google Talk plugin installed then Eclipse crashes (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=334466). It's crazy for me. I thought that was Java version and with Java 6 my eclipse was still crashing. To solve this I should use gnome/GTK instead KDE. Now it works "well" (in gnome environment). Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar problem on Windows 7 x64 professional edition. Please note following steps to fix this problem.

1. tools.jar is missing from required path if you are using jdk1.7 x64 bit version.
2. Please install x86 version of jdk1.7
3. Set JDK_HOME="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_67" and update path environment variable as path="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin"
   Note: Linux put the proper path.
4. Launch 32 bit application from /android-studio\bin folder.

I tested and verified these steps on windows 7 with 32 bit jdk1.7

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you don't have jdk installed in your machine. I had exact same problem in first run. Open a terminal (**CTRL+ALT+T**) and type: `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`

When done setup Java environment variable. Steps as follows:

1. `sudo gedit /etc/environment`
2. Either in the beginning or end of the file write: `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386` (location may vary depending on the installation of your Java)
3. `export JAVA_HOME`
4. save and exit editor.
5. Load the path variable again using the terminal: `. /etc/environment`

Couple of helpful links for further clarifications:

- [How to install JDK on Ubuntu (Linux)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14788345/how-to-install-jdk-on-ubuntu-linux)
- [How to set JAVA_HOME for OpenJDK?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175514/how-to-set-java-home-for-openjdk/175519#175519)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 7 just run the studio.bat file in your android-studio/bin folder with right click as an administrator. Now you get ask to import previous studio settings. Ignore this and on the next dialog you can specify the path to your jdk directory.
That's all.

Marcel

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when I was referencing

```
 [drive]:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65
```

in my JAVA_HOME environment var instead of the Android Studio recommended

```
[drive]:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79.
```

I am using the x64 version of the JDK on Windows 10 Pro.

**From the Android Studio installation instructions.**

*Before you set up Android Studio, be sure you have installed JDK 6 or higher (the JRE alone is not sufficient)—JDK 7 is required when developing for Android 5.0 and higher. To check if you have JDK installed (and which version), open a terminal and type javac -version. If the JDK is not available or the version is lower than version 6, download the Java SE Development Kit 7*

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=studio

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 things you must check:

1. verify that `/etc/environment` file has the correct `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` values referring to your Java installation directory.
2. verify that you have the correct Java version (maybe you are using a distribution of Linux which need a server version of Java) you may need this version like my case [JRE for server](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/server-jre8-downloads-2133154.html).

Answer (score 0):

On my Linux Mint 17.3 install, I found [these instructions](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1372) incredibly helpful.

The problem seems to boil down to the system's default Java being OpenJDK and Android Studio preferring Oracle's JDK. I actually did not perform the OpenJDK removal steps given in the tutorial, but only downloaded the Oracle JDK and set it as my system's default. Android Studio worked right away.

In case the linked page ever goes away, the steps I took were

Download Oracle JDK. Mine was version 1.7.0_79.

```
tar -zxvf jdk-7u79-linux-x64.tar.gz
sudo mkdir -p /opt/java
sudo mv jdk1.7.0_79 /opt/java
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/opt/java/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/java" 1
sudo update-alternatives --set java /opt/java/jdk1.7.0_25/bin/java
```

and

```
java -version
```

confirms the system is using Oracle's JDK, giving output like

```
java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```