# Not able to start Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, classpath, java-home, tools.jar

I have gone through all these links.

[Android Studio can't Start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16578321/android-studio-cant-start?lq=1)

[Error to run Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601334/error-to-run-android-studio)

i have also set

`Path- C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin`

`JAVA_HOME -C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05`

My android studio is in this path - C:\Users\ram\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio

But still I get this error message could someone please help me.

**error message**

```
tools.jar seems to be not in Android Studio classpath.
Please ensure JAVA_HOME points to JDK rather than JRE.
```

My OS is windows 7 32 bit.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I also had the same problem and found this post from Stackoverflow. Solved the issue. [Stack Overflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27528652/tools-jar-seems-to-be-not-in-android-studio-classpath-on-windows-8)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, just setting the JAVA_HOME variable correctly fixed it for me.

- Are you sure you have the (latest) Java development kit installed and active/running? Type in CMD `java -version` to see the version.
- You sure the environment variable is correct? Type in CMD `setx JAVA_HOME C:\path\to\jdk`, not JRE.
- Maybe just a reboot helps?
- Did you try a new clean install? For me (Win 7 64) and what I have read about setting up android studio it should be a walk in the park compared to other IDE's.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change the variable path in Environment variables (control panel). Make a new variable & give path of jdk version like `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25`.

If you have like this JAVA_HOME `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25` in system variables than just edit it & replace `JDK1.8.0_25` with `jre1.8.0_25` thats it.