# Can't start Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

After installing Android studio， I can't start it. There is no response any more after click it's icon.I open the bat file named “studio.bat” in "C:\Program Files\Android\android-studio\bin"，run it in cmd window, I found that:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\mtk81346>"C:\Program Files\Android\android-studio\bin\studio.bat"

C:\Documents and Settings\mtk81346>IF EXIST "" SET JDK=

C:\Documents and Settings\mtk81346>IF NOT "" == "" GOTO jdk

C:\Documents and Settings\mtk81346>IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Android\android-st**udio\bin\\..\jre**" SET JDK=

    C:\Program Files\Android\android-studio\bin\
    \..\jre

C:\Documents and Settings\mtk81346>IF NOT "" == "" GOTO jdk
```

Comment: lol it is a 0.1 beta, so yeah GL

Comment: Did you ever find a fix?

Comment: Please check [my answer here. It solved the issue.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574189/android-studio-installation-on-windows-7-fails-no-jdk-found/16574700#16574700)

Answer (score 5):

Add the environment variable JAVA_HOME to the latest jdk path.

Comment: where do I set this variable?

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 12.04. I've set it on .bashrc but the problem still persists. My Java is open-jdk. I'm not sure if that is the problem...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have JDK_HOME or JAVA_HOME System Variable set to the path of the JDK.

Secondly, I had an issue using an older version of the JDK (1.6.x).  When I upgraded to 1.7.x, and modified the System Variable JAVA_HOME to that path (didn't include /bin), I was able to get Android Studio running.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue. Starting the bat in a cmd gave me `Unrecognized VM option '+UseCodeCacheFlushing'`. I then removed that one from the file `studio.exe.vmoptions` in the bin folder of the studio installation and it started right away.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your system variables, and simply remove the "/bin" from JAVA_HOME or JDK_HOME, this worked for me.

Comment: i think it depends if your java files has been moved to other location and now are not inside the folder /bin, the default folder..