# Android studio isn't opening on Windows

Tags: android, windows, android-studio

I just downloaded and installed Android Studio. For whatever reason, it won't open. I've tried running it as administrator, but that doesn't seem to work either. I've also tried uninstalling and reinstalling, but I'm still having this same problem.

Comment: Why is this getting down-voted? I really want to try it out and have absolutely no idea why it won't open. I stated what I had tried prior to posting this. Don't really see any problem with my question. If you're gonna downvote, at least explain why.

Comment: You should provide more info than it won't open. Are you getting an error or something to point us in the right direction? Did you follow the guide?

Comment: I provided all the information I had available to me. No error, it literally just won't open. I followed the guide exactly.

Comment: Odd what version of windows?

Comment: Have you updated to the latest android SDK?

Comment: Figured it out! See the answer I posted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Studio installation on Windows 7 fails, no JDK found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574189/android-studio-installation-on-windows-7-fails-no-jdk-found)

Comment: Not a duplicate. Even though I had set the JAVA_HOME variable on installation, it was still doing this

Comment: This is Win10 IE11 and studio64 does not finish closing threads. Simply does not run, gets stuck before showing any window.

Comment: Delete the folder: C:\Users\{user name}\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio{version} and set JDK_HOME environment variable to your JDK's ROOT directory.

Comment: For Windows 7 all Android Studio versions since 2022 don't work with symptoms like Java SDK, JAVA_HOME, etc  Don't waste the time - downgrade the version to Android Studio 4.0.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Figured it out! I'm sure someone will run into this in the future, so here goes.

Even though it found my JDK during installation, it wasn't able to find it when I was trying to open it, for some reason. Simple fix. Add a `JDK_HOME` environment variable to your system variables. It should contain the path to your JDK's **ROOT** directory. i.e. `c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\`

Comment: I tried this but it isn't working for me. I have the same problem you had initially.

Comment: @LarryMcKenzie Nope. I try to open it by double-click or open through the right-click menu and nothing comes up. I don't even see it in the processes.

Comment: @idigyourpast: did you follow this link..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574189/android-studio-install-on-windows-7-fails-no-jdk-found?rq=1

Comment: @Jeet Yes, and it didn't work, either. I uninstalled it and reinstalled it as "Make available to everyone" or whatever the option was, and it is working now. Can't really explain it.

Comment: @idigyourpast Are you positive you pointed to the root directory and not bin?

Comment: @Willem Ellis you are right neglect the bin.. in your path variable

Comment: Worked for me as well!!
By the way, it's worth noticing that - if you are on x64 - you need to point at a 32 BIT JDK, because the application is 32 bits.
Keep this in mind!!!

Comment: @AndreaRaimondi You are my saver! Thank you for your comment, that was the only solution that helped me!

Comment: Glad this is still helping people 8 years later!

Answer (score 102):

On windows open task manager and check if android studio is there.
End the task and start the app again it works like a charm

Comment: This worked for me. I have been using AS for years and never encountered an issue like this. I have seen this with other applications before though. Running Windows 10 if that info is useful to anyone.

Comment: actually this is the correct answer to this question. just go to task manager by right clicking on the task bar and  in the background tasks find android studio and right click on it finally click on end task and everything is fine. Now restart your studio

Comment: @Anandakrishnan I do believe that is what I have written

Comment: This doesn't work to me

Comment: Actually it worked. The problem was that I have been searching for another entry instead of searching studio64.exe.

Answer (score 49):

For me this technique works

- Hover on icon, then hover on app
- Press right click and select maximize

[image]

Comment: This solved my issue, appears that I had it open on an external display previously. Thanks!

Comment: Nice. Very odd behavior from AS

Comment: on the new Windows 10, You no longer get this option when you right click. Another fix is to use ALT + SPACE , then you will get the option

Comment: Thank you, this solved it when I had AS opened previously in a 4K screen and went back to my regular 1080 screen.

Comment: @YonkoKilasi you can right click to get the behavior, but you have to hover first so that you see the preview and then right click on the preview.

Answer (score 20):

OS: Windows 10 64bit

Need to delete below folder and try launch Android Studio again.

> C:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1

Source: [developer android](https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues#studio-config-directories)

Comment: it will delete the settings

Answer (score 16):

This link http://tools.android.com/knownissues lists another cause for the launcher malfunctioning. 
I quote the link here:

"
On some systems the launcher script does not find where Java is installed. Workaround is to set a variable indicating the location of Java [b/55281]:

1. Open Start menu > computer > System Properties >  Advanced System Properties
   In the Advanced tab > Environment Variables, add new system variable JAVA_HOME that points to your JDK folder, for example C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21.
2. Another issue we found is that the launcher script uses an option that is unknown to Java on some system [b/55267]
   Open the installation folder of Android Studio (e.g. C:\Programs Files\Android\android-studio, or C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio) and find the "bin" directory in there.
   Open a "cmd.exe" (command prompt), cd to the android-studio\bin folder and run "studio.bat". You will most likely see an error: for example  b/55267 is about the option -XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing not being recognized. Report the error, remove the line from the studio.exe.vmoptions or studio64.exe.vmoptions and it should now work.

Apologies for this weak launcher."

Comment: I had this same problem and tried the JDK_HOME fix listed above. That didn't work initially. But after reading narasi's post and running studio.bat from the command prompt, it opened. I was then also able to open it from the executable.

Answer (score 16):

I am Installing Android Studio 4.1.1 in my Windows 10 and trying to open as normal as well run as administration both ways but did not open as regular.

When I saw in **Task Manager** then it was run as a background process then simply I was **Endtask** it in that background process and re-open. It works for me...!!!

Comment: This actually solved my problem. I uninstalled the entire product, reinstalled it, and it still did not launch. Not until I detected that a Android Studio process was running after reading this answer.

Answer (score 3):

Just add a JDK_HOME variable with the path of your JDK as value and start the IDE again. That's the only thing to do, hope this closes the other questions.

Answer (score 3):

Windows 7 user: 
I tried all the above ideas ( adding JDK_HOME, JAVA_HOME environment variables), but the final trick was to run as admin.

If that fails, try "where java" in cmd.exe.
If it lists *c:\system32\java.exe* first, then rename the file.

Comment: I also was in this scenario, adding the variables did not work, but changing permissions on the Android Studio folder to allow Users/Admin did work for me.

Answer (score 2):

(i) Open the folder where android-studio is installed. (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio)

(ii)- Right click on the android-studio folder and scroll to properties.

(iii)While in Properties window, click on Security.

(iv)Click the Edit Button

(v) Select User/Admin...or others

(vi)Check "Allow" in front of "Full control"

(vii) Either Apply or Press OK

....At this point you have to wait for it to install....Enjoy!!!

And I use Window 8...!!! So same thing applies to Window 7...wonder why the security on it...

Answer (score 2):

I am on Windows 8 64 bit machine.

I already had JDK installed and jdk.1.7.0 folder was present in C:\Program Files\Java. But path for that folder didn't work. You must have jdk.1.7.xxx folder present on your machine and give that folder as JDK_HOME in Environment variable.

[image]

You can take latest JDK version from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html)

Make sure to choose Windows x64 version. Install JDK and then set your path. For those who are not sure how to set path in Windows 8, I have got following screenshots.

Go to bottom right corner. Click on Settings. Click on PC Info.

[image]

Click on Advanced System Setting link on left side.

[image]

Click on Environment Variables button. A Winodw will open with 2 listboxes. Click on New button below System variables listbox. New Window will pop up. Provide name as JDK_HOME and path as your path like "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55". No need to take bin folder into the path.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

None of the above mentioned solution worked for me. And there is no studio.bat file in bin directory.
So, I downloaded a 32-bit android-studio for my system (as it is 32bit) from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads) (official website) and it worked!

PS: The link might be broken in the future, just google for the 32 bit android studio.

Answer (score 2):

(After wasting half a day on it, finally, I got it running)

I am running it on **Windows 8.1**. Also, I had JDK 1.7.0_13.

I tried the following:

1. Open Start menu > Computer > System Properties > Advanced System Properties In the Advanced tab > Environment Variables
2. Add new system variable **JAVA_HOME** that points to JDK folder, C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_13\
3. Just to be on the safer side, also add new system variable **JDK_HOME** that points to JDK folder, for example, C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_13\
4. Append new PATH in system variable that points to JDK folder, C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_13\

**But still it didn't work.** Then it struck me that might be, my Java version is old. I downloaded the latest version from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html/).

I uninstalled JDK 1.7.0_13 and installed version 8 i.e. JDK 1.8.0_131.

Now do all the above steps but, replace the path with C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\ **OR** whichever your latest version is.

**Success!!** Now it works.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I have existing projects and during trying the opening Android Studio, it just showed me the name of the project.

The thing I did was changing the name of that project and forcing Android Studio to ask me to choose which project at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was a windows related bug. Android Studio was configured properly and working like a charm, but it was opening in the second disconnected windows.

My solution was to press **[Win] + Tab** and then choose Android Studio on half of the screen so that it readjusts. Finally, I maximized it and it opened it in the correct screen.

Comment: This happened to me, too. Android Studio 4.1.was waiting for me with a dialogue in another windows desktop. Mine is a chocolatey installation which was updated some weeks ago and I didn't test if it worked. Once I opened it, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve the same issue by refer to the solution provided in Android Developer Portal,

[Studio doesn't start after upgrade](https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues#studio-config-directories)

If Studio doesn't start after an upgrade, the problem may be due to an invalid Android Studio configuration imported from a previous version of Android Studio or an incompatible plugin. As a workaround, try deleting (or renaming, for backup purposes) the directory below, depending on the Android Studio version and operating system, and start Android Studio again. This will reset Android Studio to its default state, with all third-party plugins removed.

For Android Studio 4.1 and later:

Windows: %APPDATA%\Google\AndroidStudio Example: C:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1

macOS: ~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio Example: ~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1

Linux: ~/.config/Google/AndroidStudio and ~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio Example: ~/.config/Google/AndroidStudio4.1 and ~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio4.1

Answer (score 2):

In my case executing these in the command line worked after ending the Android Studio process in the task manager:

```
net stop winnat
net start winnat
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the log file in :

```
C:\Users\<yourid>\.AndroidStudio<version>\system\log\idea.log
```

It might give you some clue.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to reinstall the Android Studio. In my case, I just deleted "C:\Users\User.AndroidStudio3.5" folder. Then Android Studio is opened. The folder contains just personel settings such as your ide theme darcula etc.

Answer (score 1):

I invalidated cache and restartI deleted the Android studio version folder which was C:\Users\User.AndroidStudio3.5 for me and it worked like charm.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was simply rebooting the computer. I'm certain that logging off and logging in will work to so the environment variables can refresh on profile level after installation.

Answer (score 1):

Change the JAVA_HOME system environment variable to C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre

The direct path to installed java may not work sometimes due to version conflict.

Answer (score 1):

Zuhair Naqi's solution is good, but in my case I don't have the option to maximize. **So I found another method**, because in my case the Android Studio (Bumblebee) does not open every time the windows was updated.

- Select right click on the android studio icon, and **open some recent project**.
- A new window will open with the recent project correctly.
- You close the window that you couldn't see, and from there you can open projects normally.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had Android studio crash on my machine crying about ram. Then it just wouldn't start again. Restarting  th ecomputer wouldn't help and I know it has nothing to do with Java.

What ended up fixing it was runing Android Studio trough the Start Menu, or the instalation folder and not the pinned icon ...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not using two Languages (Hindi + English) as input method because android studio install required some time stamp and suppose you are using Hindi language that time and letters will not match at the time of opening 
**Solution is** - select primary Language as English while installing Android Studio.
*To change steps*

1. press Windows
2. search word language
3. remove Hindi Language

[image]

4. then install Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

I edited `studio.bat` file.

I added actual jdk placement to `SET JDK=` line at the beginning of file:

`SET JDK=C:\\\Program Files\\\Java\\\jdk1.8.0_151`

Answer (score 0):

You must upgrade to 4.0.1 version!

Answer (score 0):

The same problem happened with me. Actually my C drive wasn't full still I wanted to install android studio in D drive. The problem was resolved when I deleted it and again installed android studio.

**Install it in C drive (You don't have to do anything for that. Actually, just click next...next.. next.. while installing and you are done.
)**

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by going to control panel and uninstalling android studio, then restarting the computer so that any running instances would close. Next I deleted the folder

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
```

Re-installed everything, and everything was working fine.