# Android studio does not run

Tags: android, android-studio

Android studio does not run in Windows 8. I download it, install, but when i press on icon to run it - nothing happens. I try to run with admin. I try to set compatibility with Windows 7.

Comment: I'm sure this question will be appearing a million and one times in the next couple of weeks, but [this seems to be the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16579521/1270789). You need to set the `JDK_HOME` environment variable to point to your Java installation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Studio install on Windows 7 fails, no JDK found?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574189/android-studio-install-on-windows-7-fails-no-jdk-found)

Comment: My problem was caused because the character '&' was in the path (in my Windows username).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For debugging it is very helpful to start `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\bin\studio.bat`.

That points out what is wrong. In my case I had to update my `JDK_HOME` environment variable to point to the currient installation.

From the android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) (this part was published after I wrote my answer):

> **Known issue:** On some Windows systems, the launcher script does not find where Java is installed. If you encounter this problem, you need to set an environment variable indicating the correct location.
>
> **Select Start menu > Computer > System Properties > Advanced System Properties**. Then open **Advanced tab > Environment Variables** and add a new system variable `JAVA_HOME` that points to your JDK folder, for example `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21`.

Comment: As for me problem was that the variable JAVA_HOME was not set too.
Control Panel - System - Advanced system settings - Environment variables 
add JAVA_HOME with value c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\ for example (if yoour machine runs under win).

Comment: Yeah indeet I missed to add this :)

Comment: Optionally you can add %JAVA_HOME%\bin to PATH string - this allows you to run commands from \Java\jdkxxx\bin\ directly without specifying full path. "java -version" for example

Comment: Google should have added an error message. This problem (which should not be there in first place) is wasting time of millions of developers.

Answer (score 2):

The launcher is not finding your JDK setup. Make sure you have correctly set one of these environment variables: `ANDROID_STUDIO_JDK`, `JDK_HOME`, `JAVA_HOME`

Comment: Thank you for answer. I was facing same issue for Ubuntu. I configured JDK_HOME by following command: export JDK_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-i386