# android studio AUTOMATICALLY closes

Tags: android, android-studio

I installed android studio in windows 7 but it just closes immediately after opening. I've installed java jdk also and  added a JDK_HOME environment variable  But android studio closes itself after few seconds.

Comment: i am facing the same issue,and i dont think any thing is wrong with the jdk path.

Comment: Geez this question needs way MORE upvotes. Since I've updated to the latest Android Studio version is working like s!$t. I've been trying everything, use Oracle's JDK, use the default JRE wrapper, change the Gradle settings. The most annoying thing is that it just closes, I don't see any error nor log.

Comment: Same here and it's not from jdk.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out! I'm sure someone will run into this in the future, so here goes.

Even though it found my JDK during installation, it wasn't able to find it when I was trying to open it, for some reason. Simple fix. Add a JDK_HOME environment variable to your system variables. It should contain the path to your JDK's ROOT directory. i.e. c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\

source [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16579521/2169192)

**Answer-2**

see this link also [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16580845/2169192)

Comment: I have done that. But android studio does open but closes automatically after few seconds.

Comment: follow the link 2 so that you can understand where the error occurred. and tell the exact problem so that we can assist

Comment: Running Windows 10 on a 64 bit, I shutdown and restarted. Problem went away.

Answer (score 2):

I have two versions of JDK installed on my computer and get the same problem.
x64: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91
x86: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55

Solved by pointing the JDK_HOME to x86 path.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was changing the gradle version which caused this because of a known bug, I commented here on what worked for me but I recommend you read through the whole thing

https://github.com/ConsensusJ/consensusj/issues/7