# Android Studio not Opening after closing it

Tags: android, android-studio

After I close out the Android Studio tab, I am not able to open it again. I am not able to open Android Studio until I uninstall and reinstall the software. Every once in a while, the screen will go gray and I am forced to reinstall again.

I have tried right clicking and selecting 'open', but it doesn't do anything.

I expected Android Studio to open after clicking on it, but it is as though I never installed it at all. It only works until I close the tab.

Update:

I went into my files and clicked on one called 'Studio'. It gave me an error titled Error launching Studio. Here is what it said:

```
Failed to load JVM DLL C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jre\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll 
If you already have a 32-bit JDK installed, define a JAVA_HOME variable in Computer 
> System Properties > System Settings > Environment Variables.
```

Comment: Update: I went into my files and clicked on one called 'Studio'. It gave me an error titled Error launching Studio. Here is what it said: Failed to load JVM DLL C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jre\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll      If you already have a 32-bit JDK installed, define a JAVA_HOME variable in Computer > System Properties > System Settings > Environment Variables.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android studio isn't opening on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579334/android-studio-isnt-opening-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the cache files from user-> appdata-> android studio

- On Windows: %USER_HOME%.gradle/caches/
- Use your uninstaller to remove all the cache, registry, files, temp then restart install new version of android studio to different location.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a problem with Android Studio a few weeks ago when my antivirus was removing a file needed to launch the app on my device.

I had to re-add the library file that it would keep removing before I caught that it was proudly telling me that it was removing that file to quarantine.

Long story short check that your antivirus is not removing the file.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the same issue by refer to the solution provided in Android Developer Portal,

[Studio doesn't start after upgrade](https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues#studio-config-directories)

If Studio doesn't start after an upgrade, the problem may be due to an invalid Android Studio configuration imported from a previous version of Android Studio or an incompatible plugin. As a workaround, try deleting (or renaming, for backup purposes) the directory below, depending on the Android Studio version and operating system, and start Android Studio again. This will reset Android Studio to its default state, with all third-party plugins removed.

For Android Studio 4.1 and later:

Windows: %APPDATA%\Google\AndroidStudio
Example: C:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1

macOS: ~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio
Example: ~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1

Linux: ~/.config/Google/AndroidStudio and ~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio
Example: ~/.config/Google/AndroidStudio4.1 and ~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio4.1