# I am try to open Android Studio but not opening?

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, android-studio-3.0

I have installed **Android studio** the latest version **3.*** 2 months ago. At that time i have setup JVM etc. all stuff. The last few days ago it was working very fine was a little slow. but after that I am trying to open but it is not opening. i check my **JAVA_HOME** all king of setting form Google but not working. i watched many videos and applied many solutions but no any solution working my side. I have re-installed this. after this not working. I think someone is blocking my app. because i checked in Task manager it is not showing it's processed.

[image]

[image]

> **my studio.exe.vmoptions**  i changed..

```
-server
-Xms512m
-Xmx1280m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=500m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-XX:CICompilerCount=2
-Dsun.io.useCanonPrefixCache=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf
-Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off
-Djdk.module.illegalAccess.silent=true
-Djna.nosys=true
-Djna.boot.library.path=
-da
```

I have attached an image that shows my installed directory of **Android Studio**. please note that my system is 32 bit and i installed 32-bit Android studio.  i share that image to show that why **studio.exe** icon gone removed. that was working in last night and i closed my studio normally.

Comment: Could you tell exactly what happens when you open Android studio?

Comment: nothing is happing. no process in task manager.

Comment: last day i normally close the studio. as every one does. but after that in moring, it stops working.. please help

Comment: reinstall may be helpful

Comment: i have already done this. that is already mentioned in description.

Comment: @ankitasingh Have you tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579334/android-studio-isnt-opening-on-windows)

Comment: yes today i seen that.. but not working

Comment: i am also try to open 64bit but not working.