# Android studio is not opening AFTER changing studio64x.exe.vmoptions or deleting it

Tags: android-studio

I have changed studio64x.vmoptions file to make studio faster but ever since I made change, android studio  is not opening. it shows error about JAVA_HOME environment variable but I already have added that. please help!

tried reinstalling android studio, adding Java_Home , deleting studio64x.exe.vmoptions. still not opening

Comment: Can you describe the exact changes made to the file to make it faster?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android studio isn't opening on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579334/android-studio-isnt-opening-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the same issue (Android Studio was not opening) by refer to the solution provided in Android Developer Portal,

[Studio doesn't start after upgrade](https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues#studio-config-directories)

If Studio doesn't start after an upgrade, the problem may be due to an invalid Android Studio configuration imported from a previous version of Android Studio or an incompatible plugin. As a workaround, try deleting (or renaming, for backup purposes) the directory below, depending on the Android Studio version and operating system, and start Android Studio again. This will reset Android Studio to its default state, with all third-party plugins removed.

For Android Studio 4.1 and later:

Windows: %APPDATA%\Google\AndroidStudio Example: C:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1

macOS: ~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio Example: ~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1

Linux: ~/.config/Google/AndroidStudio and ~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio Example: ~/.config/Google/AndroidStudio4.1 and ~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio4.1