# Android Studio Is Not Opening After Setting JDK_HOME

Tags: android, android-studio

I recently downloaded Android Studio 4.1.1 (Processor: AMD Ryzen 5 1500x Quad-Core Processor 3.50 GHz)

I also set up JDK_HOME and also tried set up JAVA_HOME to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1

I also have my HYPER-V and Windows Hypervisor Platform turned on.

I did try rebooting the system, reinstalling the android studio. I even tried editting studio.bat to set the JDK path manually.

My android studio still won't open even after doing that. Can anyone help on this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android studio isn't opening on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579334/android-studio-isnt-opening-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

this happened to me in Macbook i found the solution [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues)

Just delete **AndroidStudio4.1** folder

you can find this folder by following path

*Windows: %APPDATA%\Google\AndroidStudio
Example: C:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1*

this will work.