# Android Studio doesn't show up once started

Tags: android, windows

I know this is an old very well documented issue with Android Studio but trust me I tried everything I found on Stack Overflow old threads (solutions from 2016, 2017 which quite obviously could not work anymore in 2021).

I installed Android Studio and when I start it, it doesn't run. I tried to set JAVA_HOME, JDK_HOME, STUDIO_JDK to both the JRE folder coming with Android Studio and with the the JDK installation folder under C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2. I paid attention to run studio64.exe since my java -version say I'm running a 64bit version

```
java version "15.0.2" 2021-01-19
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 15.0.2+7-27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 15.0.2+7-27, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I can run studio.bat but the IDE doesn't show up, I simply have this

```
2021-04-13 10:22:21,156 [    438]   WARN - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Problems found loading plugins:
  The Google Sceneform Tools (Beta) (id=google-sceneform-tools, path=~\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\plugins\google-sceneform-tools, version=1.8.0) plugin defines no module dependencies (supported only in IntelliJ IDEA)
2021-04-13 10:22:21,923 [   1205]   WARN - Container.ComponentManagerImpl - Do not use constructor injection (requestorClass=com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator)
2021-04-13 10:22:23,121 [   2403]   WARN - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - keymap "ReSharper" not found [Plugin: com.android.tools.ndk]
2021-04-13 10:22:23,398 [   2680]   WARN - nsions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl - Extension to be removed not found: class org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.execution.test.runner.TestClassGradleConfigurationProducer
2021-04-13 10:22:23,757 [   3039]   WARN - Container.ComponentManagerImpl - Do not use constructor injection (requestorClass=org.jetbrains.android.compose.AndroidComposeAutoDocumentation)
2021-04-13 10:22:23,908 [   3190]   WARN - Container.ComponentManagerImpl - Do not use constructor injection (requestorClass=com.android.tools.idea.apk.ApkProjectComponent)
2021-04-13 10:22:23,909 [   3191]   WARN - Container.ComponentManagerImpl - Do not use constructor injection (requestorClass=com.android.tools.idea.apk.issues.SetupIssueReporter)
2021-04-13 10:22:25,326 [   4608]   WARN - ugins.textmate.TextMateService - Missing builtin bundles, checked:
C:/Users/emanu/AppData/Roaming/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/plugins/textmate/lib/bundles
C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/plugins/textmate/lib/bundles
2021-04-13 10:22:26,007 [   5289]   WARN - com.intellij.util.xmlb.Binding - no accessors for class org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.highlighter.KotlinDefaultHighlightingSettingsProvider
2021-04-13 10:22:26,487 [   5769]   WARN - Container.ComponentManagerImpl - Do not use constructor injection (requestorClass=com.android.tools.idea.gradle.notification.GeneratedFileNotificationProvider)
2021-04-13 10:22:26,522 [   5804]   WARN - Container.ComponentManagerImpl - Do not use constructor injection (requestorClass=com.android.tools.idea.apk.editor.notification.ApkReloadNotificationProvider)
2021-04-13 10:22:26,701 [   5983]   WARN - Container.ComponentManagerImpl - Do not use constructor injection (requestorClass=com.android.tools.idea.apk.ApkWritingAccessProvider)
2021-04-13 10:22:27,007 [   6289]   WARN -            #com.android.ddmlib - * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
2021-04-13 10:22:27,044 [   6326]   WARN -            #com.android.ddmlib - * daemon started successfully
2021-04-13 10:22:27,512 [   6794]   WARN - openapi.wm.impl.ToolWindowImpl - ToolWindow icons should be 13x13. Please fix ToolWindow (ID:  Problems View) or icon jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Android/Android%20Studio/lib/icons.jar!/general/warning.svg
2021-04-13 10:22:30,409 [   9691]   WARN - Container.ComponentManagerImpl - Do not use constructor injection (requestorClass=com.android.tools.idea.apk.symbols.DebugSymbolNotifications)
2021-04-13 10:22:31,417 [  10699]   WARN - dering.imagepool.ImagePoolImpl - 0 maxSize for Bucket. This Bucket will not be used.
2021-04-13 10:22:32,088 [  11370]   WARN - Container.ComponentManagerImpl - Do not use constructor injection (requestorClass=com.android.tools.idea.lang.androidSql.room.RoomDependencyChecker)
```

I see the initial Android Studio splash screen but then the process CPU usage goes down to 0% and the RAM keeps at 1GB. I see a process linked to the "hello_ar_java Android Studio" windows but I don't see this window.

[Here a screenshot of the processes linked to Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmXwX.png)

So apparently the Android Studio is running, the initial welcome project started but is doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so turns out you can't have your JAVA_HOME environment variable pointing to your own installation of Java. It has to be pointing to the JRE that comes with Android Studio.

Step 1: Delete any JAVA_HOME and JDK_HOME environment variables

Step 2: Copy the path to the jre folder inside your android studio installation

Step 3: Create new JAVA_HOME and JDK_HOME environment variables with the value as the path copied in step 2.

Android Studio should now open. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds crazy but I finally found the answer to my question. I hope it will be useful o someone having the same issue. You can find it here

[Android studio isn't opening on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579334/android-studio-isnt-opening-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Check task manager for apps Or process  consuming resources and terminate these, if you are not using them, then restart android studio this worked for me.