# Facing issues when installing android studio

Tags: android

I'm trying to install android studio. After finishing the installation process when I'm opening it. It's not opening. Search a lot about it but to figure the issue.

[screenshot of window where I'm facing problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4NN5.png)

When I'm clicking the finish button the app is not opening. JDK is properly installed in my laptop. My laptop's process is Pentium quad core

Comment: It's impossible to infer what's wrong with the information you've provided. Maybe you can check the logs, you can google for how to check logs

Answer (score 2):

I believe your system configuration is not up to the task. These are the  minimum requirements for android studio.

```
64-bit Microsoft® Windows® 8/10.
x86_64 CPU architecture; 2nd generation Intel Core or newer, or AMD CPU with support for a Windows Hypervisor.
8 GB RAM or more.
8 GB of available disk space minimum (IDE + Android SDK + Android Emulator)
1280 x 800 minimum screen resolution.
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running it in Admin mode? and the same thing for the installer.

Otherwise, there's a common issue with Android studio, sometimes it can't detect the path of your JDK, try adding `JDK_HOME` to your environment variables and the value should be the **root** to you **JDK** `c:\Program Files\Java\YOUR_JDK_VERSION_HERE`
[question]: [Android studio isn't opening on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579334/)

Comment: I had tried it but it doesn't work.Please suggest other ways

Comment: Can you share your system configuration?  you should make sure its sufficient to run Android studio

Comment: Yes ofcourse, Processor is intel pentium quad core and ram is 4gb

Comment: To run Android studio, you should have an 8GB RAM Minimum and better CPU