# Android studio doesn't start

Tags: windows-7, android-studio

I just download Android Studio for Windows 7, the wizard went ok up to the end but now when I click on the shortcut or on the .exe to start the program nothing happens, no error, no new window, it's seems like it is doing nothing. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Studio installation on Windows 7 fails, no JDK found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574189/android-studio-installation-on-windows-7-fails-no-jdk-found)

Comment: I don't think this should be closed. The installation *didn't* fail, and there was no clue that "no JDK found" was the cause. The title of this question is *not* a duplicate of the other one.

Comment: @UncleZeiv the main part of the flagged duplicate question is, "However, when attempting to launch the application from the desktop icon, nothing happens". This is an almost identical problem.

Comment: For Windows 7 all Android Studio versions since 2022 don't work with symptoms like no Java SDK, JAVA_HOME, etc  Don't waste the time - downgrade the version to Android Studio 4.0.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It's a bug of Android Studio 0.1v

You should add `JAVA_HOME` to the system environment variables.

http://tools.android.com/knownissues#as0.1

- Open Start menu > computer > System Properties >  Advanced System
  Properties
- In the Advanced tab > Environment Variables, add new    system
  variable `JAVA_HOME` that points to your JDK folder, for example `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21`

Comment: And do you know how to solve the bug of the double icon on the taskbar?

Comment: well, I didn't suffers 'Double icons'.

Answer (score 10):

1. Install latest [Java Development Kit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html).
2. Set path in system variables for Java (ie *C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin*)
3. Set JDK_HOME system variable (ie *C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21*)
4. If not working, set JAVA_HOME in system variable too (ie *C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21*)
5. If not working, check if you don't have spaces at the ends of the lines in system variables (PATH, JDK_HOME, JAVA_HOME)

You don't have to restart computer after changing system variables, just reload command prompt (if you are using it).

If it still not working, you probably have **java.exe** in **C:/Windows/System32/**. Rename it, restart command prompt and type **java -version** to check if you are using correct version of JDK.

I've posted tutorial [how to fix Android Studio](http://blog.vyvazil.eu/how-to-fix-android-studio-which-doesnt-start/) with screenshots on my blog.

Comment: Thanks! The problem was that I had java.exe in C:/Windows/System32/
Just renamed it and it worked! Probably gonna delete it too lol

Answer (score 3):

I have had a similar problem with Android Studio 1.0 in windows 7 x64. When I ran studio64.exe it flashed the android studio logo and it disappeared immediately. Also I tried

```
studio64.exe > error.log
```

to figure out possible errors. `JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25` environment variable was correctly setted.

Finally I decided to uninstall all Java versions (I had a mess of different java versions installed), both jdk and jre and reinstalled last version jdk 1.8.0_25. My problem was solved.

Regards,

Comment: i'm getting "access is denied" (in admin mode)

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it might get stuck in memory. Open task manager, terminate android stuido. Open it up again.

Answer (score 2):

If you install new the version of android studio.
It requires new jdk 1.8. 
Just install the latest jdk 1.8 and android studio will work without the need to manually edit any environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a new system variable named ANDROID_STUDIO_JDK or JDK_HOME with the path to your JDK install folder, such as C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact problem and did try to do every thing manually nothing worked except for this command when I finished it finally launched. Open CMD with administrator if possible then put the following command:

```
set path="$PATH":C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin
```

Then just try to launch it should work.
This is the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have Java 1.8 (JDK) or higher and update java_home and path to this version. 
I did every tips but i checked AS requirements and updated jdk do 1.8.xx

Answer (score 1):

It's possible there is a problem with your username (and name of the user folder). It shouldn't contain non-latin letters.
I had solved my problem (no response to an attempt to run Android studio) when I tried running the application as another Windows user (with name that consists of English letters only)

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem, but with no error message.

I found a `studio.bat` file and dig in it. There, I found some tips:

I found out thet the variable suggested in a previous post is incorrect.
`ANDROID_STUDIO_JDK` is no good.
`STUDIO_JDK` is the one.

Also, just to make the things/solution worst to corner,
I've uninstalled jre and jdk then reinstall jdk only.

The setup variables are like this:

- `JAVA_HOME` is now pointing to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\bin`
- `JDK_HOME` is pointing to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172`
- `STUDIO_JDK` is pointing to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172`

It's a mess but it's working...

Is it because I uninstalled/reinstalled java sdk and jre? or just the env. variables? who knows :)

Specs:

- i5 with 4gig ram
- win 10 32bit

Answer (score 0):

In addition to following the steps pointed out by Tigris I also had to run the Android Studio with Administrative rights. Not sure why but I just made it in a few minutes ago.

1. Follow the steps here: http://tools.android.com/knownissues#as0.1
2. Run Android Studio as Admin

Answer (score 0):

There is **Another Issue**

http://tools.android.com/knownissues

open a "cmd.exe" (command prompt), cd to the android-studio\bin folder and run "studio.bat". You will most likely see an error: for example  b/55267 is about the option -XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing not being recognized. Report the error, remove the line from the studio.exe.vmoptions or studio64.exe.vmoptions and it should now work.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a process still running in the background that would need to be killed in the task manager. The name of the process is studio64.exe (at least that's the name on my machine). Could be because I am running a 64-bit OS. After killing this process, try to run Android Studio again, and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If your path and/or environment variables are not pointing to the correct JDK, things won't work properly.

A rock solid solution, especially if you must have multiple JDKs installed (e.g. Java 6/7/8) is to create a batch file to launch Android Studio.

Create a new file called `studio.bat` and place this somewhere **outside** the Android Studio installation, e.g.

```
c:\mydevstuff\launchers\studio.bat
```

(if you put the batch file anywhere in the `android-studio` folder, then you'll have problems when updating Android Studio).

Put the following code in the new batch file:

```
@echo off

REM Can make paths relative to SCRIPT_PATH if necessary
set SCRIPT_PATH=%~dp0

set ANDROID_STUDIO_JDK=<JDK Path>
set JAVA_HOME=<JDK Path>
set PATH=<JDK Path>\bin;%PATH%
cd <android-studio Install Path>\bin
start studio64.exe
```

Replace `studio64.exe` with `studio.exe` if you need the 32-bit version.

Replace

```
<JDK Path>
```

with the path to your JDK, e.g.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25
```

Replace

```
<android-studio Install Path>
```

with the path to your Android Studio installation, e.g.

```
C:\Program Files\Android\android-studio
```

Now you can just run the batch file to start Android Studio.

Additional:
If you want to pin to the Taskbar, then create a shortcut to the batch file and then change it's target to:

```
cmd.exe /c "<path to bat>\studio.bat"
```

Then pin this shortcut to the Taskbar by drag-and-drop.

You can also set it's icon from the original Android Studio `studio.exe` file.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem and these steps fixed it.

- Remove ALL older JRE / JDK versions
- Set values for JDK_HOME & JAVA_HOME to path of JDK install

Answer (score 0):

if you use android studio version 2.3.3 **you should have JDK with version 1.8** in the system environment values ,
to add it 
**click on Computer (in windows 7)
System properties 
Advanced system settings (at the right)
Advanced (tab) 
environment variables button** 
and edit the value of name  JAVA_HOME  to the file which contains jdk 1.8
if you don't have this variable make a new one