# Android Studio can't find Java SDK in Windows 8

Tags: android, sdk, java, android-studio

The new Android Studio has a strange problem when you run the installer in Windows 8. Even after installing the Java SDK and setting JAVA_HOME it still complains that it cannot find Java, which it is looking for under C:\windows\system32. The only solution I've found is to delete java*.exe from system32, but obviously this is not ideal (although you can replace them from the sdk dir afterwards). Is there something I'm missing? Also does anyone know why those 3 java exe files end up in System32 in the first place?

Comment: Are you sure is java working properly in your machine ? I mean in cmd or in eclipse etc.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem.
Probably, you have **java.exe** in **C:\Windows\System32** folder.
Rename this file and try installing again.

BTW, there are few related posts to check out.

[Android SDK installation doesn't find JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382178/android-sdk-installation-doesnt-find-jdk?rq=1)

[Android studio doesn't start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16582107/android-studio-doesnt-start)

Answer (score 1):

Try opening Android Studio through the App menu instead of the file manager.