# In my Android studio path/bin, there is no studio.bat file

Tags: android

[Picture of my bin folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R64HM.png)

As you can see there is no studio.bat file...I reinstalled my Android studio, i installed the newest sdk,i tried those "make a new environmental var" answers but i didnt manage to fix the problem.

Sorry for my bad english doe,
I would appreciate every single answer...

Comment: What is your exact problem? Why you need studio.bat? If you want to run android studio you can able to see `exe` files named `studio.exe` or `studio64.exe` is available.

Comment: I forgot to mention, when i run the Android Studio splash screen comes up
and just disappears without any error or message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android studio doesn't start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16582107/android-studio-doesnt-start)

Comment: Already tried that one.

Comment: Check for log file in your home directory `c:/users/--username--/.AndroidStudio2.2/system/log/idea.log` and post the log to identify the exact issue. If you are using Linux or Mac the location might change. Above i mentioned the location for android studio 2.2. if you are using any other version check in the respected directory.

Comment: [link](http://www.filedropper.com/log_1) there it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i didnt manage to fix the acctual problem so i just recovered the system restore point.

From a week ago, and that worked fine.