# Android Studio Not Loading

Tags: android, android-studio

After Google Announced Android Studio based on IntelliJ I wanted to give it a try but I'm having an issue. It installed fine, and during the install successfully found the JDK but when I try to launch it nothing happens. No error, no splash screen no nothing.

Has anyone else had this issue?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: [This has already been answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574189/android-studio-install-on-windows-7-fails-no-jdk-found)

Comment: You can find the answer here...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574189/android-studio-install-on-windows-7-fails-no-jdk-found

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to add a new system variable named `ANDROID_STUDIO_JDK` or `JDK_HOME` with the path to your JDK install folder, such as `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\`

Comment: Thanks for your help working now

Answer (score 0):

Yes what you need to do is add a new system variable or JDK_HOME with the path to your JDK install folder, for me it "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21"