# Android Studio doesn't works

Tags: android, ide, android-studio, googleio

I have installed Android Studio, and I found some troubles. First I couldn't install it because didn't found the JDK, the solutions were two, change the name of the jre folder or install the 32-bit version of java, after the installation it does not run, doesn't do anything.
Can somebody help me?, I have Windows 8 and my pc is a VAIO VGN-NW230T, maybe the processor is old, I don't know, thanks.

Comment: I works right now apparently were the paths Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the fix for Windows 7 that worked for me. More details can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/16583198/2345220.

I would be interested to know if it works in Windows 8 as well.

Answer (score 0):

you need to install JDK and add the envoirment variable JDK_HOME with path of your jdk