# The selected directory is not a valid home for Android SDK

Tags: android, android-studio

I am an android programmer, i use eclipse. i want to try android studio, thus, i download it and tried to open it.

it says that i have to put the sdk path.

#### what i have tried

i tried to set it to my the `android-sdk` which eclipse is working on it. that sdk is up to date and have all the supports, apis ...etc.

**also**

i found a question here in the stackoverflow about my problem: [Android-studio Selected directory is not valid home for Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16606301/android-studio-selected-directory-is-not-valid-home-for-android-sdk)
The solution was to open the android studio and then press `f4` and then go to platform setting and the press the `plus` green sign then select the sdk then select the path to my `android-sdk`, i did all of that but android studio keeps telling me that the

`The selected directory is not a valid home for Android SDK`

#### any help would be appreciated

Comment: If you are on Windows, try to set the `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` environment variable to the android SDK folder you want to use.

Comment: None of the answers here worked for me but this one did.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21794272/android-sdk-is-missing-out-of-date-or-is-missing-templates-please-ensure-you

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found the solution myself, the answer was to run android studio as an administrator :P

Comment: Thi is the best answer. Also, just to add a small detail: When you open Android Studio, it will still ask to enter the sdk manager path. Ignore this message, go to Tools > SDK Manager then click on the folder of the sdk manager and click next next next. That's it!

Answer (score 11):

Had the same problem.
I was trying to select

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-XX
```

But what I actually had to do was to select `android-sdk` folder.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
```

Then I was able to choose the API I wanted from a list of APIs that would show up.

Comment: The poster specified that the error was when trying to set the path to android-sdk

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem, select SDK folder (NOT SDK->sources or SDK-platforms)

Comment: The poster specified that the error was when trying to set the path to android-sdk

Comment: I think what he is suggesting here is not to select one of the subfolders, but to select the android-sdk-macosx root folder itself.

Answer (score 3):

I found another solution make sure that you have write access to that directory. That fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

Another way this may need to be fixed is by making sure there is at least one SDK 
platform installed. Run in the commandline from the `android-sdk` folder:

```
.\tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat platforms;android-XX
```

where XX is the any Android SDK version.

Answer (score 1):

It might occurs, if Android Studio tries to open the previous project with ".idea" directory. Well, solution is to remove that folder and .iml file too.

Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

What helped for me was moving the android sdk to a folder without any special characters (e.g. no "Program Files (x86)").

Answer (score 0):

In intellij idea File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart

Answer (score 0):

I solved it from here
http://www.blog.teamguru.in/2018/04/06/selected-directory-is-not-a-valid-home-for-sdk/

1- Just close current error window and let run the android studio
2- open sdk manager as shown in below

3- Clik on Edit sdk location as below

4- Simply press next button if there is correct location for sdk you want to install there

5- let it be downloaded

6- install platform and SDK tools and

7- Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was I copied the previous Android Studio settings from my old computer, and then I imported them. But I didn't copy the old SDK! Probably the SDK path is also configured somewhere in the old settings. Instead of download them, Android Studio kept complaining about my SDK location. Finally, I also just copied the old SDK directory and then the problem was solved.

Answer (score -1):

Problem Statement selected directory is not a valid home for sdk

I have resolved from here

http://www.blog.teamguru.in/2018/04/06/selected-directory-is-not-a-valid-home-for-sdk/

1- Just close current error window and let run the android studio 2- open sdk manager as shown in below

3- Clik on Edit sdk location as below

4- Simply press next button if there is correct location for sdk you want to install there

5- let it be downloaded

6- install platform and SDK tools and

7- Enjoy