# Error while install Android Studio- SDK

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, java-6

First i faced a error after install Android Studio, and someone told me re-install again last version from website. I did it, and now i faced a  new problem it asked me to attach SDK & JDK file

i already downloaded  **sdk-tools-windows-3859397.zip**

after that i attached the file of [image: SDK]  and it give to me this error

please Help me how to solve this problem.

Comment: Have you tried the solutions for these same questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18100212/the-selected-directory-is-not-a-valid-home-for-android-sdk and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16606301/android-studio-selected-directory-is-not-valid-home-for-android-sdk

Comment: actually when i set up the android studio from website the file is not include SDK file so they said or talking about "android-sdk" and not able to find it

Comment: Please add the error Thank you