# Error: Please provide a path to the Android SDK

Tags: android, sdk, android-studio-2.1

After installing the Android studio and launching it I am getting this error.
[image]

I cannot specify the path to the SDK. I have tried giving the path as `:C:\Development\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\"`  but the path is invalid

Comment: try with `C:\Development\Android\android-sdk-windows\`

Comment: I have tried it and it's not helpful

Comment: just add upto **:C:\Development\Android\sdk**

Comment: I did that and I am getting "invalid path" error.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I encountered this problem when installing Android Studio 3.0.

There was in fact no folder named `C:\Users\Your Name\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk` after I installed Android Studio. I tried installing the Android command line tools at this location, but android studio did not accept this. (Turns out, the command line tools are not the SDK.)

Managed to fix it by doing a complete uninstall of Android Studio, deleting the `C:\Users\Your Name\AppData\Local\Android` folder, deleting any Android Studio settings folders (in my case `C:\Users\Your Name\.AndroidStudio2.3` and `C:\Users\Your Name\.AndroidStudio2.3`). After reinstalling and opening Android Studio, it gave me a dialog to download the SDK.

I can think of 2 possible explanations why this worked for me:

- Originally, Android Studio was opening a project straight away, which didn't trigger the "download your sdk" dialog. (This no longer occurred since I deleted my Android Studio settings.)
- There was some kind of setting that made Android Studio think I already had the SDK downloaded.

Comment: I had the same problem. A project was already open. After I closed the project, AS prompted me to download an SDK.

Comment: Yes, closed the project after upgrading Android Studio and got the right prompts to automatically update the SDK.

Comment: Same here @KenDeLong, I had a project already open and when I closed it, AS prompted me to download the Android SDK. Thanks for the tip. Although I have another question about AS, whether or not you need to d/l the Android SOURCES for each SDK version and no one has replied yet (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59404778/android-sdk-do-you-need-to-download-sources-with-android-api-versions).

Answer (score 67):

Try this:

- close this box then
- **Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager**

[image: 1 image]

[image: 2 image]

Comment: Lifesaver! This is probably the easiest way when the SDK tools aren't located in C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk for whatever reason.

Comment: That's strange that you have to `edit SDK path` to finally `install it`. But it solved my problem!

Answer (score 6):

Try this - `C:\Users\Your Name\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`

Replace `Your Name` with the name of your PC.

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful.

Comment: In Linux, is path similar?

Comment: I tried this path but its saying that "Invalid Android SDK Path", directory or files not exist. I tried to open this path in my Computer, But in Android which is after "Local\Android", There is nothing. Its empty!

Comment: Nothing installed at this path, though I'm using IntelliJ rather than Android Studio (same core product).

Answer (score 2):

This problem is usual after you update, or reinstall the Android Studio.. Follow these steps-
* Close all the opened project which is opened by default after you started the Android Studio.. and again open the Android Studio, it will direct you towards re-downloading of SDK components from the net (So be sure to have net connectivity at this point)..
* If above step doesn't work, then restart the PC and open Android Studio again..

Hope it will help..

Comment: Android Studio comes with default Android SDK, instead of downloading new SDK which is quite time taking if internet is slow than you must provide default Android SDK path to it. BTW your answer will help those who want to download new component or android version or related library

Comment: Helped me, just closed the opened project and AndroidStudio guided me through the installation of the SDK. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered this issue when updating my Android Studio after a couple of years of not using it, and the solution ended up very easy:

I exited the window with the SDK prompt and closed the old project it was trying to open. Once the project was closed, the IDE was able to prompt me with the download window, and there SDK download worked!

Answer (score 0):

I was also stuck with this...i tried everything mentioned above, but could not get through.

Then I was about to uninstall and reinstall the IDE as mentioned above.

When I was about to uninstall, to my surprise, I found Android SDK Tools in control Panel -> Programs and Features, which was the thing I was looking for!

[Android SDK Tools in Control Panel -> Programs and features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Munx.png)

I didn't know how to find the path of that, because even after searching in my computer, I didn't get it. So, I went on further and clicked on uninstall.
    There, I found the path of Android SDK Tools "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\". I did not uninstall anything.

I linked this path in the dialogue box, the error was gone!

Whoever encounters the same error, should look for the "Android SDK Tools" in the programs and features in control panel, and then go for uninstalling the same.
There you will find the path of the tools folder.
Copy and paste that path, and you shall get through.

Answer (score 0):

When installing Android Studio on my Mac I accidentally cancelled the dialog box that would normally have installed the SDK. To fix this I deleted Android Studio from `/Applications`, and deleted the following folders:

```
% cd $HOME
% rm -rf Preferences/AndroidStudio3.4
% rm -rf Logs/AndroidStudio3.4
% rm -rf Caches/AndroidStudio3.4
% rm -rf Application\ Support/AndroidStudio3.4
```

(Adjust the version number for your version.) I then reinstalled Android Studio and let it guide me through the SDK installation process.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone get to experience the same weird situation as me:

I had installed Android Studio, had projects saved, but for some reason I had to do reinstall Windows (and during that I deleted my "Android-folder" in ".../local". When you do that, you will encounter the exact same pop up.

No worries, close it and even though it says that it is needed, it's not. You just don't have access to the prior projects. When saving the new one, then everything will be OK.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by downloading the SDK again, in my case I had deleted the SDK folder that was in `C:\Users\george\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`, because I deleted it then I had to download the SDK

Answer (score 0):

I just reinstalled Android Studio (everything) C:/user/yourName/.androidStudio.4 and C:/user/yourName/.androidStudio.4.
You dont have to delete your projects folder!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, going to the Settings menu in Android Studio, there I could download the SDK (none were installed) through the "edit" button

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when moving a project from one computer to antother, even though it wasn't an Android project and didn't need an Android SDK.

The solution for me was to open the file local.properties and remove the line that says `sdk.dir`. Hope this can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is close the project opened in android studio. This error occurs when you reinstall Android Studio. The previous project that you have been working on will be opened by default. Select that folder from file explorer and move into different location and then again launch Android Studio. The SDK installation will begin thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

### **The Reason that why Android Studio can't install/find SDK automatically:**

As I tried many times for reinstalling Android Studio, but each time I faced with this SDK popup. I figured out that after installing, Android Studio seeks for project folder automatically (usually located in `C:\Users\Username\AppData\AndroidStudioProject`) to syn previous settings, gradle, SDK path, Android Studio Settings etc. When I deleted this folder (if you need your previous projects copy it somewhere for latter replacement) the usual installation has been started after clicking on `install`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the AppData folder was set to hidden, unhiding it worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).