# Android SDK - Do You Need to Download Sources with Android API Versions?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-manager

I am using Android Studio and its SDK Manager to download API versions for Android development.

I am wondering if I need to download the "Sources" items for the API versions I want to work with (see screenshot below). I don't need to change any source code or anything like that; I'm just doing normal Android development.

[image: Android Studio SDK Manager]