# An issue with Android Studio running on Linux

Tags: android, android-studio

I have recently installed Android Studio on Manjaro Linux, but I am experiencing issues every time I have to run the application from the scratch. Namely, in order to start application, I have to be logged in as root, then I have to validate JAVA_HOME environmental variable and finally start the application with ./studio.sh

Here is the full code of that:

```
[nikodroid@manjaro ~]$ cd /usr/share/applications/android-studio/bin
bash: cd: /usr/share/applications/android-studio/bin: Permission denied
[nikodroid@manjaro ~]$ sudo su
[sudo] password for nikodroid: 
[root@manjaro nikodroid]# cd /usr/share/applications/android-studio/bin
[root@manjaro bin]# ./studio.sh 
which: no java in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl)
ERROR: Cannot start Android Studio\nNo JDK found. Please validate either STUDIO_JDK, JDK_HOME or JAVA_HOME environment variable points to valid JDK installation.
[root@manjaro bin]# cd /usr/java/
[root@manjaro java]# export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_21/
[root@manjaro java]# export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
[root@manjaro java]# cd /usr/share/applications/android-studio/bin/
[root@manjaro bin]# ./studio.sh
```

So, obviously this runs only when I am keeping the terminal session, once I exit, the application stops working. My question is, what can I do in order to not do this all every time I want to run the application?

Just to mention, I put the following line

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_21/
```

in /etc/environment/ in order to persist this environment variable, but it seems that it didn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: How did you install android-studio on Manjaro?

Comment: Related solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17688188/can-not-start-androidstudio-only-in-console/34379855#34379855

Answer (score 9):

It really was a permission issue, as I looked and found out that the owner and group were messed up, so what I did is changing the permission/ownership with:

```
chown -R root:root android-studio
```

After this, I just changed the dir with:

```
cd /usr/share/applications/android-studio/bin
```

and ran

```
./studio.sh
```

It loaded the application without any errors.

Comment: so it appears you are now running android studio as root? please don't do that.

Comment: unless the key point is just that you are in the `root` group but not in the group that was previously set. In which case, `chgrp -R root` is sufficient, but still not optimal. Check which group owns that directory and either add yourself to that group, or change the group to one that represent this better. (`users` for example). You can also create a group just for that (e.g. `android-devs`). Create the group, add yourself to it, the give the ownership of the directory to that group.

Answer (score 3):

install JRE and JDK with apt

for JRE: sudo apt-get install default-jre
for JDK: sudo apt-get install default-jdk

check if all is ok with: java -version

then continue installation Android Studio

Answer (score 1):

A similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574189/android-studio-installation-on-windows-7-fails-no-jdk-found?rq=1) (but in Windows) was solved

> adding a system variable JDK_HOME with value c:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\

So, try, adding:

> JDK_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_21/

to your /etc/environment (as well as keeping JAVA_HOME).

---

UPDATE:

Try fixing permissions for "/usr/share/applications/android-studio/bin" and "./studio.sh".

Comment: I've added JDK_HOME under JAVA_HOME in /etc/environment, but I still have to write all the commands in shell, as I wrote in my first post.

Comment: Well, it seems there are two different problems. Did JDK_HOME solve the "ERROR: Cannot start Android Studio\nNo JDK found. Please validate either STUDIO_JDK, JDK_HOME or JAVA_HOME environment variable points to valid JDK installation."?

Comment: After I do following:

[root@manjaro java]# export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_21/
[root@manjaro java]# export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

I am able to start Android Studio, but only while the current session lasts. When I want to start a new session, I have to type all from the above again.

Comment: Seems to be a permission issue.

Comment: Fixed it by changing permissions/ownership. Worked without any glitches after it :)

Comment: By the way, it would be nice if you marked my answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the content of

```
/usr/share/applications/android-studio/bin
```

are executable (the directory as well) by the **group**. (probably the group `users`). Then make sure your user is in that group.