# Can not start androidstudio only in console

Tags: java, android, linux, android-studio, sudo

Hi my problem is the next, I downloaded `Android Studio` and if I go to

> /path/android-studio/bin

and I execute `studio.sh`

I get the following error:

```
No JDK found. Please validate either STUDIO_JDK, JDK_HOME or JAVA_HOME environment variable points to valid JDK installation.
```

Now if I export `JAVA_HOME`

```
 export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/
```

and execute `studio.sh` Android Studio works but now I create a `Symbolic Link` to `studio.sh`

```
ln -s /path/android-studio/bin/studio.sh /usr/bin/androidstudio
```

and if I run `androidstudio` in console this one works, but now I want to create a `Gnome launcher`

So I did this:

```
vi /usr/share/AndroidStudio.desktop
```

and I put the next code into the file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Android Studio
GenericName=IDE para Android
X-GNOME-FullName=IDE para Android - Android Studio
Comment=Desarrolla aplicaciones para Android
Exec= /usr/bin/androidstudio
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
Type=Application
Icon=/opt/android-studio/bin/idea.png
Categories=Development;
Name[es_ES]=Android Studio
```

but at the moment I run `AndroidStudio launcher` this one gives me the next error:

```
 No JDK found. Please validate either STUDIO_JDK, JDK_HOME or JAVA_HOME environment variable points to valid JDK installation.
```

I think doing again:

```
 export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/
```

Will fix the problem but no, the `launcher` still without working :C
Thank's in advance!

**EDIT**

All I did it as `su` user.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, even though I had configured JDK_HOME and JAVA_HOME, Android studio would not start.
The problem turned out to be that we don't need to have to `sudo` a program t make it work.  I had installed Android Studio into `/usr/local` and did `sudo ./studio.sh` to start it but it complained it couldn't find the JAVA_HOME and JDK_HOME variables. But when I installed it into my `home` folder, it worked without any problem by directly running `./studio.sh`.

The problem for a new user might be about realizing that most copy, move and`rm` operations in `/usr/local` result in needing to use `sudo`, and so a person might use `sudo ./studio` when in `usr/local`, which is unnecessary and the system searches for the root user's configuration of JAVA_HOME and JDK_HOME which it does not find.

Answer (score -1):

Open studio.sh and after the lines:

```
MKTEMP=`which mktemp`
RM=`which rm`
CAT=`which cat`
TR=`which tr`
```

add

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/latest
```

And that's it!