# android studio not launch in windows 7 32 bit

Tags: android, windows-7, android-studio

I am was downloaded android studio an installed on my OS (its windows7 32 bit) and not appear any wrong but when I run it not open any things, and I follow this question [Android Studio installation on Windows 7 fails, no JDK found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574189/android-studio-installation-on-windows-7-fails-no-jdk-found) also same thing ??
any one have any idea about that??

this my JDK
[image]

and this my environment
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If it does no error but not launch it's environement probleme

Add this to your Environement change the path or jdk version if you have an other one but don't change the variable name

JDK_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21

Comment: Again no error message or launch? Try to launch it from windows shell to see error message

  And don't know if it's important but i have add it to user variable not systeme variable

Comment: what you mean from windows shell?? you mean from c:\programsfile\android tudio??

Comment: I mean the cmd prompt http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/947-command-prompt.html

Comment: thanks for replay and sorry I didnt this way before, I do as in pic http://img20.imageshack.us/img20/1101/89537334.jpg , please write command to run application from windows shell

Comment: just type "studio.exe"
And not "cd studio.exe"

Comment: not happen any thing see picture http://img842.imageshack.us/img842/8297/86676788.jpg , I typed "studio.exe" and studio.exe bu as you watching

Comment: do you see the logo one seconde or nothing?

Comment: I installed on 64 bit and it works, I thik it didnt work on 32 bit

Comment: Hum i have a 32 bits W7 and it's work it's really strange you have nothing to tell you what happend but if you can work now it's ok :P

Answer (score 0):

variable name has to be JAVA_HOME not JDK_HOME

Comment: I did cahanged it to JAVA_HOME and same problem, no launching