# Android Studio installation issue in ubuntu

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[Android Studio installation on Windows 7 fails, no JDK found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574189/android-studio-installation-on-windows-7-fails-no-jdk-found)
I am facing same problem on ubuntu 12.04. 
I have download JDk and android studio. Same Problem of that link facing peoblem

```
No JDK found. Please validate either ANDROID_STUDIO_JDK, 
or JDK_HOME or JAVA_HOME points to valid JDK installation
```

**EDIT**

now facing this problem

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_21/bin/java: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting ")")
```

see this image of my problem [see this](http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=7645e0d)

Comment: Have you installed JDK 7 ?

Comment: Yes, its already installed..

Comment: and have you set it's path in .bashsrc ?

Comment: one thing that often saves me some headache is to create my own shell script in which I set `JDK_HOME` and then launch the IDE.

Comment: @Ali give me ur script

Comment: @Lucifer how to set path in .bashsrc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following steps, to set JDK Path in uBuntu

edit your ~/.bashrc file and add the paths as follows:

insert following lines:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/<your version of java>
export PATH=${PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}/bin
```

Comment: opps, try this `echo $path`

Comment: there is not any chat room

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem combining Jerome's and Jerod's answer:

Install JDK -- sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
Environment Variable -- `sudo nano /etc/environment` adding the following line:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-i386
```

Reboot, and Android Studio starts up. (I had added also a link to studio.sh to the main menu).
Also I just found https://stackoverflow.com/a/17827697/2533809 which seems to have a nice write-up, pretty much the same answer.