# Android Studio not detecting my installed jdk

Tags: android, java, android-studio

I'm getting this while installing the Android studio.

[image]

I have installed the latest JDK7 on my system, and also set path in environment variables.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16574189/558991

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see on your screenshort, you should set **JAVA_HOME** environment varible.

How to do that (Windows):

1. Right-click the **My Computer** icon on your desktop and select **Properties**.
2. Click the **Advanced tab**. Click the
      **Environment Variables** button. Under System Variables, click **New**.
3. Enter the variable name as **JAVA_HOME**.
4. Enter the variable value as the installation path for the Java
   Development Kit.
5. Click OK.
6. Click Apply Changes.

Comment: do you know how to import actionbar sherlock in android studio. I have updated to the latest version of android studio and tried alot about this but not success .

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to go to `windows/system32/` and find `java`. Then just change the name `java` to `java.exe` for that file.

Comment: Please avoid unnecessary use of upper-case characters. It looks like shouting.