# Can't launch Android Studio

Tags: android, ide, android-studio, launching

I installed succesfully Android Studio on Windows 7 64bit, but it fails at launching. The following screenshots illustrate what happens.

[image: Trying to launch Android Studio]
[image: After previous error dialog]

I read the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574189/android-studio-installation-on-windows-7-fails-no-jdk-found/16574523#16574523) but still have not found the solution.

I've done the following things:

- Set environmental variables JDK_HOME, ANDROID_STUDIO_JDK and JAVA_HOME to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\"
- Set them to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17"
- Download msvcr100d.dll and placed it on "C:\Windows\System32\" and "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\"
- Reinstalled Android Studio

Still having the same issue. Can't see where the problem is. How can I solve this?

Comment: kindly provide the environment variable for jdk

Comment: I have those three variables with the same value right now (which is "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\"), but only those variables. Are you referring to another variable I must set?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just found the solution.

I tried to launch Android Studio from the Start menu, which provoked that issue. So I tried to launch from its main directory and it worked. The shortcut target path was wrong.

Shortcut target path Before:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\bin\studio64.exe
```

Real executable path:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\studio.exe
```

The `studio.exe` and `studio64.exe` inside bin folder doesn't work, but the one in android-studio seems to work perfectly. Just change the shortcut's target to that path and you're ready to launch it properly from the Start Menu.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was one found from the resource: [www.faqforge.com/windows/fix-the-program-cant-start-because-msvcr100-dll-is-missing-from-your-computer-error-on-windows/](http://www.faqforge.com/windows/fix-the-program-cant-start-because-msvcr100-dll-is-missing-from-your-computer-error-on-windows/)

> What hides behind this name is the Microsoft Visual C++
>   Redistributable which can easily be downloaded on the Microsoft
>   website as x86 or x64 edition:
>
> 32 bit: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5555
>
> 64 bit: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=14632
>
> Usually the application that misses the dll indicates what version you
>   need – if one does not work, simply install the other.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, for the problem of the missing DLL file, u must install (Microsoft Visual C++ 2010), I used the same links provided earlier:

32 bit: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5555

64 bit: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=14632

Second u need to download and install Java SE Developement Kit (JDK), and go to Enviromental Variables like it is said in the error message; there u must create a new entry JAVA_HOME with the path to the JDK u just installed