# Android Studio - 'tools.jar' seems to be not in Studio classpath using jEnv

Tags: java, android, android-studio, osx-elcapitan, jenv

I'm using [jEnv](http://www.jenv.be/) to manage my Java environment. I tried to launch Android Studio but it fails with the following error message (with a fresh download - just to be sure):

```
'tools.jar' seems to be not in Studio classpath. 
Please ensure JAVA_HOME points to JDK rather than JRE.
```

I used the export plugin so that jEnv sets my JAVA_HOME environment variable for me.

Here's how it looks in my terminal:

```
jenv global
> 1.8.0.65

java -version
> java version "1.8.0_65"
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)

javac -version
> javac 1.8.0_65

echo $JAVA_HOME
> /Users/****/.jenv/versions/1.8.0.65

ls /Users/****/.jenv/versions/1.8.0.65/lib/
> ant-javafx.jar    ir.idl      missioncontrol  sa-jdi.jar
> ct.sym        javafx-mx.jar   orb.idl     tools.jar
> dt.jar        jconsole.jar    packager.jar    visualvm
```

So I can see the tools.jar, that's why I don't get why Android Studio can't launch.

I'm on Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.3.

By the way I read the top voted answer of [tools.jar seems to be not in Android Studio classpath on Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27528652/tools-jar-seems-to-be-not-in-android-studio-classpath-on-windows-8) but it said that you should copy the jar, which makes me think a really ugly way to fix the problem (I haven't tried it yet but I hope this not the only solution).

Has anyone experienced this issue and knows how I can fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so finally I uninstalled `jEnv` and uploaded my JDK to its latest version (u71).

After setting my bash profile with `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)`, it worked like a charm.