# Cannot determine path to 'tools.jar' library for Android API 21 Platform (/home/user/Android/Sdk)

Tags: java, android, sdk

I am a newbie to Android development.
I installed the Android studio at Ubuntu 20.04.
I have installed Java (I know that the installation was ok since I used it also at Tizen development)

I try to build a project, but an error occurs:

`Cannot determine path to 'tools.jar' library for Android API 21 Platform (/home/user/Android/Sdk)`

I manually copied the *tools.jar* file into the sdk directory but nothing changed.
Any ideas?

Comment: Did you restart Android Studio?  What directory did you copy tools.jar to?

Comment: Yes, of course!

Comment: What do you mean "of course"?  Some people wouldn't.  Especially newbies.  (And you didn't answer the 2nd question ...)

Comment: Note that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27528652 implies that `tools.jar` shouldn't be copied into the "/home/user/Android/Sdk" directory ... if that is what you did.