# running flutter app got Execution failed for task ':bluetoothadapter:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: flutter, build.gradle

I didn't change anything in my Flutter application and it was running perfectly but when i tried running on real device i got this exception
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bluetoothadapter:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not find tools.jar. Please check that C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_321 contains a valid JDK installation.
```

```
BUILD FAILED in 13s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this post for a workaround:

[tools.jar seems to be not in Android Studio classpath on Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27528652/tools-jar-seems-to-be-not-in-android-studio-classpath-on-windows-8/28718588#28718588)

It seems, the `tools.jar` is not present on every version of Java 8 anymore. Also make sure to use a JDK and not a pure JRE for development.

Maybe it is worth downloading a current version of the JDK from https://adoptopenjdk.net