# How to use Android Studio with Java 32 bit?

Tags: android, android-studio

Today I want to try migrating some of my Eclipse projects to Android Studio but I have some problems.

When I open the Android Studio, it says that I need to install 64 bit JDK. So I searched for this problem and found out you need to open studio.exe instead of the default studio64.exe

When I open the studio.exe it says that I'm running 64 bit Windows, so I need to use the studio64.exe

The problem is I need the 32 bit Java not only for Android development, and all my Eclipse are in 32 bit, so changing from 32 bit to 64 bit Java is hard for me. This may make some of my softwares not working and some other problems that might arise, and you need to change the JAVA_HOME to the 64 bit java. To avoid those things I would like to just use 32 bit Java instead of 64 bit.

I searched for this problem but I can't find any solution yet, any idea how to solve this? If there's no solution, I think I'll just keep using Eclipse..

I'm using Windows 7 64 bit, Android Studio 135.1641136

Comment: Multiple JDKs can co-exist in one system. So you can have installed  i.e. jdk1.7.0_71 and jdk1.8.0.25 in both 32-bit and 64-bit versions.

Comment: @EugenPechanec but I need to change the paths everytime I want to use an application..  It's inconvenient to change that if I just want to use the Android Studio, and I found out later that Android Studio does not support NDK yet. So I think I'll just wait for now. Thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 3):

I think that the impossibility of running studio.exe without a 64-bit Java installed were an issue in that version. I had the same problem but I've just installed currently latest Android Studio (135.1740770) and ran studio.exe without any issues.

Additionally, if you're behind a proxy (like me) you may need to update the proxy parameters at C:\Users\username\.AndroidStudio\config\options\other.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse states it does not consult JAVA_HOME variable just PATH and eclipse.ini file.
https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F#Find_the_JVM

In previous versions of Android Studio there has been on option to set JDK_HOME or ANDROID_STUDIO_JDK instead of JAVA_HOME but it seems it was removed.
[Android Studio installation on Windows 7 fails, no JDK found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574189/android-studio-installation-on-windows-7-fails-no-jdk-found)

Comment: As I've stated above, I don't use java for eclipse only, I have problems using 64 bit java for other things in the past. Yes, it seems that you can set the java for the android studio in the past, but for this release there's no solution for that, it insists me to use java 64 bit.. (see the comment by eugene there)

Comment: I suggest submitting an issue to [Android Studio issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry?template=Android%20Studio%20bug)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've reported the problem here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=87369. It's good if it's a valid problem, if not, I'll just live with eclipse :)

Comment: Well the ADT plugin for Eclipse is discontinued so you won't be able to hang on that for long.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue... I guess I will just bite the bullet and install/configure 64-bit Java alongside my 32-bit version :X