# Android Studio Windows 64bit JDK 32 bit

Tags: android

I downloaded android-studio-bundle-135.1740770-windows.exe and installed android studio. But when I am trying to open, it's throwing an error like "Please install a 64-bit JDK"

[How to use Android Studio with Java 32 bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27498928/how-to-use-android-studio-with-java-32-bit)
Went through the above link but downloading that version didn't fix my issue.

And most of my applications depend on java 32 bit version and i can't install 64 bit jdk.

Is there any fix to this or I am doing anything wrong. I have the class path set correctly in the environment variables with JAVA_HOME property.