# I have no "Path" Environment variable, therefor i cant get android studio to work

Tags: java, windows-7, android-studio, environment-variables

I did a clean install of Windows 7 today - after that I installed the Java JDK and Android Studio. Now I have the [`JAVA_HOME` environment variable problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574189/android-studio-installation-on-windows-7-fails-no-jdk-found) that many before me had.

I have set `JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25`

But everyone seems to have a `PATH` system variable where they can add the path to Java JDK, but in my case, I *don't* have a `PATH` system variable.

From all the searching I have found, all solutions expects you to have the `PATH` variable. However, I found [this link](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml) that describes how to set a PATH variable, but I don't understand it.

Comment: Last time I fiddled with those on Windows the JAVA_HOME variable was defined in a different place (GUI-wise), and the other variables, including PATH was below. You might want to clarify "don't have". Are you using a terminal/cmd?

Comment: You will have a `PATH` environment variable whether you set it or not.  Windows has a default path if you don't set one.  Without a PATH variable you wouldn't be able to run any commands and your computer would be unusable.

Comment: if you have set JAVA_HOME correctly, type `echo %JAVA_HOME%` in command window and it should return the path. Otherwise, you did not do it right.