# Android Studio not running in Windows 8

Tags: android-studio

i get a " 'tools.jar' seems to be not in android studio classpath. Please ensure JAVA_HOME points to JDK rather than JRE ". I downloaded jdk in my D drive.

Comment: Have you set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to the JDK on your D drive?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Studio installation on Windows 7 fails, no JDK found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574189/android-studio-installation-on-windows-7-fails-no-jdk-found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set JAVA_HOME as environment variable

**my computer > system properties > advanced system settings**

**under advanced tab,  environment variables > system variables > new**

set variable name as **JAVA_HOME** and value as **your jdk path** (in my case C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71)

Comment: thanks :) it worked out fine after i changed it