# Could not find main class error in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-studio

Am getting this error in Android Studio:

```
Error:could not find main class com/intellij/idea/main
```

I tried all the tips like:

1. I set the variable `JAVA_HOME` as well as `JDK_HOME`
2. Generally for 64bit installation default path will be `c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_71`
3. Another thing to check if your java installation ( 64bit is compatible ) is fine.

---

a. Open command prompt.

b. `cd {your java installation}\jdk1.7.0_71\bin`

c. type `java` and `java -version` ( See if both commands work )

Still Android Studio is not working. Please help I am trying back 2 weeks but nothing helped.

Comment: Try to re-download and reinstall.

Comment: I know this has been asked long time ago but just to clarify:
"Generally for 64bit installation default path will be c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_71"
No, the one with (x86) is for 32-bit applications

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "\bin“ to path. 
Or maybe just reinstall Java & android studio.

Comment: i tried all this 3 times i reinstalled java as well as android studio

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574189/android-studio-installation-on-windows-7-fails-no-jdk-found, it might help you!

Answer (score 0):

## The best thing that worked for me

was delete the variables envioroment JAVA_HOME
JDK_HOME STUDIO_OPTIONS etc,

all the variables related to ANDROID STUDIO AND JAVA

I realized because I have another computer with android studio installed and working perfectly so I started to look up how were the variables there and it turned out that the computer didn't have any of those variables so I knew what was the problem

however, I'll attach a screenshot of my variable environment state

[image]

*If this help you please i bet you like this post sorry if my english is a little bad but all are learning from each other*

Answer (score -2):

All you have to do is

- open Control panel
- open Programs and Features
- select "run programs made for previous versions of windows"
- then choose Android Studio

After a while, your computer shall ask you to test the program. In my case it did really work

- then it will ask you to save the new settings or abort, just save it.

... and you're done!