# Could not detect JDK in the Android Studios installation

Tags: android-studio, installation, java-7, java-6, installation-path

[image]

I've tried setting up all the paths what all were suggested by programmers in the following link [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574189/android-studio-installation-on-windows-7-fails-no-jdk-found)
But still i'm getting the error. I've have attached an image regarding this, if anyone faced the same problem and were able to solve them , please do send in the procedure to solve this problem.

My Environment Variables are as follows:

--------SYSTEM VARIABLES--------------

PATH: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin;
JDK_HOME:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79
JAVA_HOME:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79

also that I'm even having 2 JDKs installed "jdk1.7.0" and jdk"1.7.0_79" , will this make any difference ?

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem. Just quit Android Studio installer, reboot after installing java sdk and restart Android Studio installert. Worked for me.

Comment: Had the same problem and after installing the jdk it was sufficient to just restart the Android Studio installer. Still a weird issue...