# Android Studio Setup - could not detect JDK

Tags: java, android, android-studio, installation

I'm trying to install the Android Studio on my Windows 7 notebook, but even when I filled the path with the JDK, occurs the following error:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qy6pE.png]

I already set the environment variables JAVA_HOME, PATH, reboot the notebook, but still have problem. I'm using the "android-studio-bundle-141.2456560-windows" version and also the "jdk-7u79-windows-x64".

Could you please, help with this issue?

Comment: it's out dated jdk please update jdk to jdk1.8.0_60 or latter then try again

Comment: I updated the JDK to "jdk-8u73-windows-x64" version, but the error still occurs.

Comment: try this suggestion http://stackoverflow.com/a/30510967/4848308

Comment: Same problem...tks @g2o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this link [Android Studio ZIP](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/latest), I did the download for windows after unzip all the file, I started execute the "studio.exe", that is inside the bin folder.

Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run java.exe -version in a terminal, if the jdk is installed it should return something like:

```
java version "1.8.0_72"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_72-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.72-b15, mixed mode)
```

if not, you might want to reinstall it and reset the path.

What you might also want to do, is go to the jdk location and make sure it contains a directory named bin and see if it has the java.exe file in it.

Comment: Thank you but I did all this things, and still not working the installation.

Comment: Accidentally, no JAVA installed in my HP Laptop win 10 i5. I install android studio version 2.2 and it works fine. Just change Virtual to active in the BIOS. What actually happen?

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded Android Studio for windows, then I unzipped all the file. I started executing the "studio.exe", that is inside the bin folder. It worked.

Thanks everyone for the help.
@Victor W. Vieira this works fine for me. On Windows Professional x64-bit system.