# Android studio Installation error - JDK not detected

Tags: android, android-studio, environment-variables, java-8

Please help me,I already installed java development kit and changed my os environment variables to JAVA_HOME. But still can not install android studio. OS is windows 10 pro. Android studio installation error_jdk could not detected 
"System check 
We could not detect a java Development kit (JDK) v 7 or newer on your system.Please browse to its path if know:
Or download the following compatible JDK: jdk.7u67-windows-x64.exe and press 'Next' after installation is complete."

Comment: Add a system variable JDK_HOME with value c:\Program Files\Java\jdkxxxx\

Comment: might it help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35609472/android-studio-setup-could-not-detect-jdk and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38941930/windows-10-android-studio-installation-jdk-error

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you installed 64 bit jdk if your system is 64 bit first. 
Secondly make sure your environment  variable is set right.

set path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin:

Comment: Thank you so much. But it s 64 bit. After jdk installation , oracle java mission control installed, but cmd "javac " not working.

Comment: If javac is not working in cmd you have not set your environmental variables right